# How to deal with a NaN in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have the following:

```
 var cID = parseInt(hash.match(/\d+/g)[1]);
```

I then want to do something like so:

```
if (cID !== undefined) {
    alert('hello');
}
```

Problem is cID if it does not find a match, is returning NaN in the console when logged... How do I create an if Statement, meaning if there is an INT from the match or not based on: parseInt(hash.match(/\d+/g)[1])

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you check that a number is NaN in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652319/how-do-you-check-that-a-number-is-nan-in-javascript)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
if (isNaN(cID)){
    //do stuff here
}
```

Comment: 869Uncaught ReferenceError: IsNaN is not defined

Comment: `isNaN(var)` does work. The issue is most likely with some other part of your program

Answer (score 3):

You might be looking for the global isNaN() function.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (cID !== undefined || !isNaN(cID)) {
    alert('hello');
}
```

Comment: Why would you need to check for undefined here? (Not challenging you, just want to know if you know something I don't).

Comment: oh I didn't really give any thought to that, I just to took his if statement and added the part he was asking about

Answer (score 1):

Use isNaN javascript function to check if return value of parseInt is number or not:

```
var cID = parseInt(somevar);
if (isNaN(cID)) { alert ('error') };
```

docs for isNaN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Functions#isNaN_Function