# Comparing NaN values for equality in Javascript

Tags: javascript, comparison, equality, nan

I need to compare two numeric values for equality in Javascript. The values may be `NaN` as well.
I've come up with this code:

```
if (val1 == val2 || isNaN(val1) && isNaN(val2)) ...
```

which is working fine, but it looks bloated to me. I would like to make it more concise. Any ideas?

Comment: Mixing `||` and `&&` without some parentheses is extremely ugly and confusing.

Comment: `NaN` and `NaN` are supposed to be unequal for a reason, because, for example, `0/0` and `parseInt("not a number!")`, while they both evaluate to `NaN`, should not be considered equal.

Comment: @Peter sometimes this difference is irrelevant to the algorithm. I think this is the case of the OP.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Try using `Object.is()`**, it determines whether two values are the same value. Two values are the same if one of the following holds:

- both `undefined`
- both `null`
- both `true` or both `false`
- both strings of the same length with the same characters in the same order
- both the same object
- both numbers and

  - both `+0`
  - both `-0`
  - **both `NaN`**
  - or both non-zero and both not `NaN` and both have the same value

e.g. `Object.is(NaN, NaN)` => `true`

Refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is

Comment: Good answer for modern javascript. Just take care because `0 === -0` returns `true` but `Object.is(0, -0)` returns `false`. For the asker's use case you might need to do `val1 === val2 || Object.is(val1, val2)`.

Comment: never knew about this +1. Thanks

Answer (score 55):

```
if(val1 == val2 || (isNaN(val1) && isNaN(val2)))
```

Nothing to improve. Just add the parentheses to make it clear to everyone.

Comment: I'd improve it with a comment explaining why should `NaN === NaN` return true.

Answer (score 26):

Avoid `isNaN`. Its behaviour is misleading:

```
isNaN(undefined) // true
```

`_.isNaN` (from [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/)) is an elegant function which behaves as expected:

```
// Is the given value `NaN`?
// 
// `NaN` is the only value for which `===` is not reflexive.
_.isNaN = function(obj) {
  return obj !== obj;
};

_.isNaN(undefined) // false
_.isNaN(0/0) // true
```

Comment: `undefined` becomes `NaN` when converted to a `Number` anyway ... imo it's much better to know that during the `isNaN` phase than after.

Comment: What's wrong with `isNaN(undefined)` being `true`? `undefined` **isn't a number**. What seems to be so misleading here for you?

Comment: @trejder: NaN and undefined are different values. Different value *types*, even.

Comment: @davidchambers: True. Which doesn't change the fact, that `undefined` *isn't* a number. Which leads us to a conclusion, that `isNaN(undefined)` *should* return `true`. The fact, that `NaN` and `undefined` are different values and different value types, doesn't change my state. As this is whole different story. Or point me out, where I'm wrong.

Comment: @trejder: We have different ideas as to which question isNaN should answer. You believe `isNaN(x)` should be equivalent to `!isNumber(x)`, whereas I suggest it should tell us whether the value of x is precisely NaN. If one wants to know whether a value is not a number, `Object.prototype.toString.call(x) !== '[object Number]'` is preferable as it doesn't allow for competing interpretations.

Comment: `0/0` and `"hello world"` are also different value *and* different value types and both `isNaN(0/0)` and `isNaN("hello world")` return `true` and I can't think of any reason one would want it to be otherwise

Comment: @drigoangelo: If you're comfortable writing `if (x !== x)` and have confidence that all current and future members of your team will understand what that does, great. If not, it would be nice to have a function which answers the question: _Is this value NaN?_ Unfortunately the built-in isNaN is not that function.

Comment: That's why we have references: To know what the meaning of a function is, and not what we guess, it is.

Answer (score 5):

`if ( val1 === val2 )`

If either one or both are `NaN` it will evaluate to false.

Also, `NaN !== NaN`

Comment: Isn't that not equivalent?  The OP wanted the expression to return true if both val1 and val2 are ```NaN```.

Answer (score 5):

NaN is never equal to itself no matter the comparison method, so the only more concise solution for your problem that I can think of would be to create a function call with a descriptive name for doing this rather special comparison and use that comparison function in your code instead.

That would also have the advantage of localizing changes to the algorithm the day you decide that undefined should be equal to undefined too.

Answer (score 5):

As long as you know these two variables are numeric, you can try:

```
if (val1 + '' == val2 + '')
```

It turns the two values into strings. A funny answer, but it should work. :)

Comment: It won't always give an identical result to the original code, but then again, in the cases where it would vary, it may be a preferred behavior. For example `"  " == 0;`, which is `true`, but will be `false` with your code. This may be considered an improvement.

Answer (score 4):

And what's about the function **Number.isNaN()** ?  I believe this must be used whenever is possible.

```
> NaN === NaN
false
> Number.isNaN
ƒ isNaN() { [native code] }
> Number.isNaN() === Number.isNaN()
true
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN

Comment: Number.isNaN(NaN) === Number.isNaN(undefined) resolves to false

Answer (score 2):

For Numeric cases the solution is fine but to extend it to work for other data-types as well my suggestion would be as follows:

```
if(val1 === val2 || (val1 !== val1 && val2 !== val2))
```

Reason being global `isNaN` is erroneous. It will give you wrong results in scenarios like

```
isNaN(undefined); // true
isNaN({});        // true
isNaN("lorem ipsum"); // true
```

I have posted a comprehensive answer here which covers the NaN comparison for equality as well.

> [How to test if a JavaScript variable is `NaN`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652319/how-do-you-check-that-a-number-is-nan-in-javascript/32137779#32137779)

Answer (score 0):

An arrow function can 'unbloat' your conditional and I would use `Number.isNaN()` instead of `isNaN()` due to the fact that `isNaN()` will try to convert the value to a number.

```
const areEqual = (a, b) => a === b || (Number.isNaN(a) && Number.isNaN(b));

if (areEqual(val1, val2)) {...}
```

Using `isNaN()` might lead to the following problems:

```
let val1 = 'a string';
let val2 = undefined;
let val3 = {};
isNaN(val1) && isNaN(val2) && isNaN(val3); // true
Number.isNaN(val1) && Number.isNaN(val2) && Number.isNaN(val3); // false

isNaN(1n); // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert a BigInt value to a number
Number.isNaN(1n); // false
```

[Number.isNaN() - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN)

Answer (score -1):

Why not an if statement like this?

```
if (isNaN(x) == true){
        alert("This is not a number.");
    }
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

Equality comparison with NaN always results in `False`.

We can go for the javascript function `isNaN()` for checking equality with NaN.
Example:

```
1. isNaN(123) //false

2. var array = [3, NaN];

for(var i = 0 ; i< array.length; i++){
  if(isNaN(array[i])){
      console.log("True ---- Values of " + i);
    } else {
      console.log("false ---- Values of " + i);
    }
}
```

Results:

> false ---- Values of 0
>
> True ---- Values of 1

Answer (score -1):

Found another way using Array.prototype.includes [MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes). Apparently, [NaN].includes(NaN) returns true for NaN.

```
function IsActuallyNaN(obj) {
  return [obj].includes(NaN);  
}
```

Or we can go with davidchambers' solution which is much simpler.

```
function IsActuallyNaN2(obj) {
  return obj !== obj;
}
```

Comment: when you write answer on SO always try to give little explanation about your code.

Comment: Don't construct an array literal just for this. If you want to use ES6 methods, use `Object.is(obj, NaN)`