# How do I test for NaN?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, nan

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Comparing NaN values for equality in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8965364/comparing-nan-values-for-equality-in-javascript)

Can anyone tell me why this is not working?

```
if(inbperr == NaN) {
    document.getElementById('inbclo').value = "N/A";
}
else {
    document.getElementById('inbclo').value = "%" + inbperr;
}
```

Instead of returning a percentage value, or "N/A", I want it to return "%NaN".

Comment: Just an alternative syntax which is DRY-er... `document.getElementById('inbclo').value = isNaN(inbperr)?'N/A':"%" + inbperr;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652319/how-do-you-check-that-a-number-is-nan-in-javascript

Comment: `function isReallyNaN(a) {
  return isNaN(a) && "number" == typeof a
 };`

Answer (score 89, accepted):

`NaN`'s are unusual: they are not equal to anything, even themselves.  You need to use `isNaN(inbperr)` to tell whether a value is a NaN or not.

Comment: For more information please read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FisNaN

Comment: `typeof NaN` ======> `"number"` WTF? No, it's *not* a number, we established that.

Comment: @charltoons It's defined by the floating point standard.

Answer (score 2):

NaN is Not a Number. One of few JavaScript toxic types. It can reduce whole expression to NaN.

http://www.crockford.com/javascript/encyclopedia/

Comment: Why "_toxic""? :] `NaN` usually appears, when you try to divide by zero. According to math (at least this, that I've learnt years ago), result isn't a number (is an infinity or something similar strange / toxic). How would you like to represent this in Javascript?

Comment: it's "toxic" because whole calculation is reduced to NaN. Ex: a*b*c/d-e+f. If any of variables is NaN whole calcultion becomes NaN. No exception, no warning, script continues to run and carry that NaN until it hits the wall. So you can find NaN in strange places.

Comment: From this point of view -- agree! :]

Comment: @whoever gave me -1 : Explain yourself or learn this topic better. NaN is toxic :)

Comment: Hmm toxic? So all those clever people who put ears into defining the IEEE floating point standard went astray here .... me thinks not!

Comment: NaN !== NaN                  // true