# Comparision of Numbers doesn't happen as expected, NaN behaviour

Tags: javascript, html, numbers

I have two variables;

```
var x = '23b';
var y = '23a';
```

Now i have a logic which will compare, if they're equal i want to perform something

Note: Both when compared, if both are NaN still they should pass the condition

i have tried using this

```
if (Number(x) == Number(y))
```

This returns false even though both are NaN

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing NaN values for equality in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8965364/comparing-nan-values-for-equality-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Why Number?

just use parseInt

```
if (parseInt(x, 10) == parseInt(y, 10))
```

The behaviour on NaN is misleading

just console this
    NaN == NaN

You will get value as false

Answer (score 0):

You can Use `isNAN`

```
var x = '23b';
var y = '23a';
if(isNAN(x) && isNAN(y))
alert("both are NAN");
```

Comment: That test is true if both are numbers, irrespective if they are equal or not.

Comment: @Traktor53 yes thats true this will compare if both are NAN and I think he has the same question.

Comment: To test if both are NaN: `if(isNaN(x) && isNaN(y))`

Comment: @Traktor53 ohh fixed it :D.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var x = '23b';
var y = '23a';
console.log(parseFloat(x)===parseFloat(y));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Object.is()`

```
var x = '23b';

var y = '23a';

Object.is(Number(x),Number(y)); => true
```

Answered here as well.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48300450/617797