# user must input a number NOT a letter or special character

Tags: javascript, isnan

I cannot seem to figure this out, very new to JavaScript. I've tried isNaN and typeof maybe I'm just writing the if statements wrong.

This is the code I have

```js
// prompt user to select password length, and what characters to include
function promptUser() {
  var passwordLength = parseInt(prompt('How many characters would you like your password length to contain?'));
  
// is length is not a number return null,
  if (passwordLength = isNaN) {
    alert('Password length must be a number.');
    return null;
  }
// password length must be greater than 8
  if (passwordLength < 8) {
    alert('Password length needs to be at least 8 characters in length');
    return null;
  }
 // length must be less than 128
  if (passwordLength > 128) {
    alert('Password length cannot exceed 128 characters in length.');
    return null;
}
```

I was expecting the

```
if (passwordlength == //(or === tried both)// isNaN)
```

to check if it is a number or not but it only spits out  `alert('Password length must be a number.');` and ignores the return null; no matter what is entered.

Comment: You may read the forms documentation... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Your_first_form

Comment: your mean is you input a number type, but also display "Password length must be a number." ?

Comment: See also [Comparing NaN values for equality in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8965364/215552)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You may be using `isNaN` wrong. Try `isNaN(passwordLength)` instead. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN

Comment: More about `NaN`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN

Comment: this fixed it thank you very much, couldnt for the life of me find a resource telling me what I was doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

You are Setting your passwordLength to `isNan` every time:

```
if (passwordLength = isNaN) {
    alert('Password length must be a number.');
    return null;
  }
```

Use:

```
if isNaN(passwordLength)  {
    alert('Password length must be a number.');
    return null;
  }
```

A single Equals `=` is a assignment operator and not a comparative operator.

Therefore your Code will go into this IF statement every time.

Please change this to a `==`, or `===` for this code to run better.

Here is some reading on the topic for you: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp

Comment: setting it equal or strictly equal only presents the problem of the code always alerting that the input must be a number even if it is a number.

Comment: You're right about `=` being the incorrect operation, however, changing it to `==` or `===` in this case will not help. The correct way to check if something holds the value of `NaN` is to use a method such as [`Number.isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN) (which is different to [`isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)), or one of the more robust solutions presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/175739/5648954)

Comment: They’re trying to check if the parsed number is a number or not, your answer suggests that using`==` or `===` will fix their code, but that’ll always skip the if I’m that case (ie: it’ll introduce the opposite issue where the if statement is never executed)

Answer (score -2):

This part `if (passwordLength = isNaN)` contains a typo. the "equal to" comparison operator is '==' or '===' (strictly equal).

Also you should compare it with null, not isNaN.

Assuming that you are using HTML for input, you will be way better off to use the <input type="number"*gt; and set the minimum and maximum values.

Comment: While you're correct about `=` being incorrect, changing this so that it checks against `null` and not `isNaN` won't help much, seeing that `parseInt()` will return `NaN`, not `null` when it's unable to parse the string to a number. Changing the operator to `==` or `===` also won't work, as `isNaN` is a function, which isn't what you would want to compare `passwordLength` against