# What does 'v !== v' expression check?

Tags: javascript

I have seen this in the sources of one lib, and confused. I think, it always evaluates to '`false`'. What is the meaning of using that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It checks whether `v` is `NaN`:

```
if( v !== v ){
    //'v' is NaN   here
}
```

From [standard](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.4):

> A reliable way for ECMAScript code to test if a value X is a NaN is an expression of the form X !== X. The result will be true if and only if X is a NaN.

**Why not just use built-in `isNaN()`?**

The answer is simple: "**`isNaN()` is not reliable enough.**". Here are the cases, when `isNaN()` will be failed:

```
isNaN("NaN")         //true
isNaN(undefined)     //true
```

Comment: Evidently the way to do it in ES6 is `Object.is(obj, NaN)`: http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:egal

Comment: @OttoAllmendinger Pretty interesting.Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

It tests for "Not A Number": `NaN !== NaN` equals `true`

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN):

> The initial value of NaN is Not-A-Number — the same as the value of
>   Number.NaN. In modern browsers, NaN is a non-configurable,
>   non-writable property. Even when this is not the case, avoid
>   overriding it.
>
> It is rather rare to use NaN in a program. It is the returned value
>   when Math functions fail `(Math.sqrt(-1))` or when a function trying to
>   parse a number fails `(parseInt("blabla"))`.