# JavaScript - Check if a variable is a number : typeof doesnt work, isNaN does

Tags: javascript, numbers, typeof

I currently face a problem, it may be very simple but I found nothing in my research...

I want to check (in JavaScript) that a variable is a number, and if it is higher than 100 or lower than 0.

I tried this :

```
if ((returnValue > 100) || (returnValue < 0) || (typeof returnValue != 'number')) { 
    //not correct
} else {
 // let's do some stuff here
}
```

But it doesn't work... When I put for example the number 50 (which is good), happening in the "if" and not in the "else" as expected !

So I did :

```
if ((returnValue > 100) || (returnValue < 0) || (isNaN(returnValue)))
```

and then I noticed that it perfectly worked !

I know too I could split that in two parts , firstly testing if the variable is a number and then if it is greater than 100 or less than 0, but this is not what I am currently looking for ;)

Could you please explain me why the first try doesn't work (and/or make it work) ?

Thanks !

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow your problem. If I use `50`, the `else` block is executed, not the `if` block: http://jsfiddle.net/bsNWW/. Maybe you are really using the string `"50"`, in which case Pointy's answer provides the correct explanation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `isNaN()` function implicitly coerces its argument to be a number. If you pass it the string "12", it returns `false`. Thus in your code the value of the variable could be a string representation of a number, and it'll make it through the tests if it's a "nice" string.

The concept of `NaN` does not really mean, generally, "not a number".  It's not really about data types. It's a feature of the IEEE floating point format. There are bit patterns that are "not numbers", and the pseudo-value `NaN` represents those.  It happens that the language designers decided to have failed numeric conversions result in `NaN` as a sort of marker.

In newer JavaScript environments, there's *another* `isNaN` function on the `Number` constructor. It differs from the global `isNaN()` in that it performs no type coercion at all, and it *only* checks to see if its argument is `NaN`.  If you pass it a string — even a string like "banana", which isn't anything like a number — it returns `false`, because no string value can be the number `NaN`.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is noted here https://stackoverflow.com/a/16988441/2624935
Basically NaN is not equal to anything even itself. So if a !== a returns true a is NaN

Answer (score -3):

Easy:

```
    isNaN(returnValue)
```

This means is Not a Number.

Comment: Yes, I know that cause I did it... But if i try if ((returnValue > 100) || (returnValue < 0) || (typeof returnValue != 'number')), and then try to put 50 : 50 is > 0 and < 100, it has number as type so...