# Javascript isNAN returns false if checking Object?

Tags: javascript

I have a script which behaves strangely.

```
console.log (typeof button);
console.log ('IsNAN ' + isNaN(button));
console.log ('isNumeric ' + jQuery.isNumeric(button));
console.log ();
```

when button is an object, isNaN should return true; Because object isNaN. However console shows differently:

```
object
IsNAN false // should be true!
isNumeric false
```

Why is that?

Edit: The Problematic script is http://flesler-plugins.googlecode.com/files/jquery.serialScroll-1.2.2.js

Line 126 @ function jump( e, button ).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you check that a number is NaN in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652319/how-do-you-check-that-a-number-is-nan-in-javascript)

Comment: Is it a blank object? It sounds like `isNaN` is type converting your falsy object to 0

Comment: note that isNaN function is broken: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN#Description

Comment: can you share how the `button` is defined?

Comment: Firebug shows that button is: a#next-photo. so jQuery or HTMLObject if I'm not wrong.

Comment: Edited, and added source of problematic script.

Comment: @Gacek: Never just link, put the code **in** the question. Links rot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> IsNAN false // should be true!

Not necessarily. :-) [`isNaN`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.4) is only true if the argument to it (converted to a `Number` if necesssary) is `NaN`.

Depending on what the object is, it may or may not be `NaN` when converted to a `Number`. It depends on what happens when the object is converted to its primitive value. `null`, for instance, converts to `0`. In many, many other cases conversion to primitive involves turning it into a string (arrays, for instance), and the default `toString` of some objects may return something that can be converted to a non-`NaN` `Number`.

Examples of non-`NaN` objects:

```
// null
console.log(Number(null));          // 0

// an array (which becomes "23" when converted to primitive, because
// arrays do `join` for `toString`; then the "23" becomes 23)
console.log(Number([23]));          // 23

// another object implementing toString or valueOf in a way that returns
// something convertable to a non-NaN number
console.log(Number(new Foo("47"))); // 47
```

...where `Foo` is:

```
function Foo(value) {
    this.value = value;
}
Foo.prototype.toString = function() {
    return this.value;
};
```

(In the above, `toString` could be `valueOf` as well.)

Comment: Wow! Nice anaswer! Thank you everyone for theirs. This one seems to be best one tho.
Didn't know that isNaN firstly tries to cast value into a number, then checks if it's NaN.

Answer (score 2):

isNaN() called with a null object is expected to be false.

If your object is not null and cannot be converted to a number then it will return true.

Answer (score 0):

I think your variable button is equal to null.

typeof(null) == 'object'

isNaN(null) == false