# Parsing numeric data item returns NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery, numbers, jquery-data

I have the following HTML table row data (within a proper table (table > tbody > tr) of course):

```
<tr id="uo_311" data-id="311" data-price="250.01111100" data-qty="1.00000000" data-value="250.26112211">
  <td>....</td>
  ....
</tr>
```

and the following jquery code to loop through the existing rows and find the place to insert a new row based on price (table is sorted by price):

```
var price = parseFloat(response['price']);
var elTable = $('#openTable');
var tableRowCount = elTable.find('tbody > tr').length;
for (var i = 0; i < tableRowCount; i++) {
    var row      = elTable.find("tbody > tr").eq(i);
    var rowPrice = parseFloat(row.data('price'));
    if (price > rowPrice) {
        row.before('<tr><td>NEW ROW</td></tr>');
        break;
    }
 }
```

The basic logic of this seems to work OK, but for some reason the statement

```
var rowPrice = parseFloat(row.data('price'));
```

returns NaN. Does anybody have any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: I guess it depends on what `row.data('price')` is during that iteration. Probably add a `console.log` statement to check the value?

Comment: have you checked wether `row.length > 0`?

Comment: And it now just started working (no code changes). I guess I was being fed some bad data from our test database. My apologies.

Comment: Use this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/2652335/1890983