# If number == NaN condition

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

it's always returns "Number"
i already tried write like:

```
if n.isNaN
if n === NaN
```

----------but it always returns second condition ""

```
var n = NaN
If (n == NaN) {return " not a number"}
else return "Number"

--"Number"
```

Comment: Use the isNaN() function. if(isNaN(n)){return 'not a number'}

Comment: Also the example works because a man compares a falsey value (NaN) with another falsey value (NaN). It is like comparing 0==0 which returns true.

Comment: You can either use the `isNaN` function or check if [`n !== n`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652319/how-do-you-check-that-a-number-is-nan-in-javascript).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reliable way to check if a value is not a number in JS is by using the isNan function.