# expect(array_values).toBeGreaterThan(Some_Value)

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor

I want to compare Array values to be greater than some value.

I tried following :

```
this.AllElements = element.all(by.css('[style="display: none"]'));
expect(this.AllElements.getText()).toBeGreaterThan(30);
```

I want to verify that all values returned by `this.AllElements.getText()` should be greater than 30.

above expect statement fails every time even all the values are greater than 30.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One straightforward option would be to use [`each()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.each) to check every single text in an array:

```
this.AllElements.each(function (elm) {
     elm.getText().then(function (text) {
         expect(parseInt(text)).toBeGreaterThan(30);
     });
});
```

Comment: for few of the getText() i am getting error : Expected NaN to be greater than 30. how can i avoid this?

Comment: @ssharma do you want these `NaN` values to cause a test failure or just skip them?

Comment: just skip them.

Comment: @ssharma then you can apply the [`isNaN` check](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2652335/771848) before calling `expect()`. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks @alecxe this helped.

Answer (score 0):

You have different ways. The first one is resolving the promise returned by protractor and use standard `Array` methods, as `every`:

```
// in this case you need to pass next callback in the block and call it after resolving the method for keeping the sync properly and communicate when the 
expectation is finished after resolving the promises 
this.AllElementsText = element.all(by.css('[style="display: none"]')).getText();
this.AllElementsText.then((texts) => texts.every((text) => (+text) > 30)).then((value) => { expect(value).toBe(true); next(); });
```

Otherwise you could work with protractor methods like `reduce` but being careful to resolving promises (same considerations for the `next` callback to be called):

```
this.AllElementsText = element.all(by.css('[style="display: none"]')).getText();
let baseValue = true;
this.AllElementsText.reduce((acc, text) => baseValue && ((+text) > 30), baseValue).then((value) => { expect(value).toBe(true); next(); })
```

In both the cases, you can avoid the `next` callback returning the promises directly from the expectation blocks.

Be also careful to manage fine all the edge cases, like you don't have texts at all etc...