# Substitute to comparing with 'NaN'

Tags: javascript

I have a component which is returning NaN whenever the component is empty. According to the coding guidelines of my project I cannot compare anything to  NaN.

Is there any workaround to this?

Comment: Would be nice to actually show us code :)

Comment: compare non-strict woth null `object != null` will also check for undefined

Comment: There is a function called isNaN( testsubject ), returns true or false.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you check that a number is NaN in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652319/how-do-you-check-that-a-number-is-nan-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to check for NaN value you can use `isNaN` function.

If you need to compare NaN with NaN you can use `Object.is(NaN, NaN); // true`

Beware `Object.is()` wont work in older browsers such as IE 11, you can use polyfill from MDN site: [click](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is#Polyfill)

Answer (score 0):

You can use isNaN() method, if your parameter is NaN, the method will return true, otherwise will return false.
In ES6, Number.isNaN() has the same effect.
I don't use "if(object typeof NaN)", you can try it.