# How to check equality of NaN javascript

Tags: javascript, nan, equality

I have been trying to check the value and type of NaN for equality but I am getting errors every time. It seems like there must be a simpler solution. Here are four possible solutions I have tried so far that do not work.  Another thing is that the underscore in the first solution is not recognized on edabit or codepen:

#### solution 1

```js
function checkEquality(a, b) {
    if((typeof a === typeof b) ||
          (_.isNaN(a) === true) &&
           (_.isNaN(b) === true)) {
      return true;
  }
}
```

#### solution 2

```js
function checkEquality(a, b) {
  let divisionByZod = 42 / "General Zod";
  let valueIsNaN = (divisionByZod !== divisionByZod);

  if((typeof a === typeof b) || (42 / 'General Zod' === true)) {

    return true;
  }
}
```

#### solution 3

```js
function checkEquality(a, b) {
  if(((typeof a === typeof b) || (isNaN(parseInt(NaN)))))  {
    return true;
  }
}
```

#### solution 4

```js
function checkEquality(a, b) {
  let c = NaN;
  if(((typeof a !== typeof b) || (isNaN(parseInt(c) !== NaN))))  {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: javaScript has the [isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) function built in.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you check that a number is NaN in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652319/how-do-you-check-that-a-number-is-nan-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

The best option to check if a variable is not a number is the isNan() function.

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN

Is good to observe that :

> Unlike all other possible values in JavaScript, it is not possible to rely on the equality operators (== and ===) to determine whether a value is NaN or not, because both NaN == NaN and NaN === NaN evaluate to false. Hence, the necessity of an isNaN function.

I don't know your use case but take in consideration that it is not possible to rely on the equality operators (== and ===) to determine whether two objects are equal or not, to this purpose the best is use Object.is() function

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is

Observe that :

> Object.is() determines whether two values are the same value. Two values are the same if one of the following holds:

both undefined
both null
both true or both false
both strings of the same length with the same characters in the same order
both the same object (means both object have same reference)
both numbers and
both +0
both -0
both NaN
or both non-zero and both not NaN and both have the same value
This is not the same as being equal according to the == operator. The == operator applies various coercions to both sides (if they are not the same Type) before testing for equality (resulting in such behavior as "" == false being true), but Object.is doesn't coerce either value.

This is also not the same as being equal according to the === operator. The === operator (and the == operator as well) treats the number values -0 and +0 as equal and treats Number.NaN as not equal to NaN.

Knowing that I think that Object.is(a,b) is the solution for your problem.

```js
const nan1 = 'a string' / 2
const nan2 = 'another string' / 2
const comparation = Object.is(nan1,nan2)
console.log(comparation) // true
```

Comment: just be careful, `Object.is` is not fully supported in all major browsers.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (isNaN(x)) {
return 'Not a Number!';
}
```

isNaN is the function you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

Try function `isNaN()`. Returns true if value NaN

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the Object.is() method. It determines whether two values are the same value. Two values are the same if one of the following holds:

- **both** undefined
- **both** null
- **both** true or both false
- **both** strings of the same length with the same characters in the same order
- **both** the same object (means both object have same reference)
- **both** numbers and
- **both** +0
- **both** -0
- **both** NaN

or both non-zero and both not NaN and both have the same value

Refer to the following documentation which

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is