# In the book 'You Don't Know JS', I have a question about isNaN polyfills

Tags: javascript, nan

In Kyle Simson's book `You Don't Know JS`,

> You can also implement polyfills more simply by applying uniqueness that NaN does not equal to itself.
>   NaN is the only value in all languages of the world "any value other than self is always equal to you."

The polyfill of the function isNaN is proposed as follows.

```js
// polyfill NaN
if (!Number.isNaN) {
  Number.isNaN = function(n) {
    return n !== n;
  };
}
```

However, is the code `n! == n` always forced to`false`? (Actually, it was the same when I made the function simple and executed it)

So I don't understand what the code means.

I would be grateful if you could explain this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you check that a number is NaN in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652319/how-do-you-check-that-a-number-is-nan-in-javascript)

Comment: @UtsavPatel Oh that's not my question but I'll read! Thank you for your information

Comment: I know that, but there are answers on that link which will answer your question.

Comment: "*However, is the code `n! == n` always forced to `false`*" but that is **not** the code you have above! `n !== n` - checks if `n` is *not equal* to `n`. However, `n! == n` checks if **not `n`** is equal to `n`.

Comment: Note that isNaN and Number.isNaN are two different things. One checks if something isn't a number and the other is completely useless.

Comment: @UtsavPatel Yup! The answers are very useful. Thank you very much!

Comment: @VLAZ Oh.... Thank you...!!!!

Comment: @Dominic Oh Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NaN` is the *only* value in Javascript which, when compared against itself with `===`, produces `false` (or, equivalently, when compared against itself with `!==`, returns `true`). Any other value, when checked against itself with `===`, will return `true`.

```
NaN !== NaN // true
const obj = {};
obj !== obj     // false
0 !== 0         // false
'foo' !== 'foo' // false
// etc, everything else other than NaN
// will produce: // false
```

So

```
return n !== n;
```

is a reliable check of whether `n` is `NaN`.