# Why won't the condition in my if statement recognise NaN?

Tags: javascript

```js
a = [1, 2, NaN];

for (const item of a) {
    if (item === NaN) {
        console.log(true);
    }
}
```

I want to be able to print `true` to the console.
Why can't `item` match up to NaN?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the rationale for all comparisons returning false for IEEE754 NaN values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565164/what-is-the-rationale-for-all-comparisons-returning-false-for-ieee754-nan-values)

Comment: Because `NaN` equals nothing, even not itself. Don't ask me why though :)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN.    NaN === NaN always returns false.   isNaN(NaN) will return true.

Comment: And while the question is asking for "why", i think this may be more catered towards what is actually desired: [how-do-you-check-that-a-number-is-nan-in-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652319/how-do-you-check-that-a-number-is-nan-in-javascript). That topic however is a bit old, and i am unsure, whether the top answers have references to [Number.isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN), which is often preferrable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hilariously, in javascript [NaN does not equal NaN](http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/the-problem-with-testing-for-nan-in-javascript.html#:%7E:text=In%20JavaScript%2C%20the%20special%20value,%3B%20%2F%2F%20Outputs%3A%20NaN%20console.). That means that you can check for NaN by doing `if(foo !== foo)`. Normally you should use the [isNan()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) function instead of that because it's way more readable.

Comment: Logically it kinda makes sense. If `(foo !== foo)` then its apparently not a number. I think the NaN being left without its "history" on how it became at this state, is why it makes sense. For example `1/0` is NaN but when assigned to a variable, the "history" is lost and thus is not comparable to another NaN with a different "history".

Answer (score 0):

Because NaN is the only thing in Javascript not equal to itself.
[isNaN()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)

```js
a = [1, 2, NaN];

for (const item of a) {
    if (isNaN(item)) {
        console.log(true);
    }
}
```