# In JS with conditional if how do I make an output that says "You typed a word, we need a number" or "negative numbers won't work here"?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

I need to have a bunch of numbers asked by prompt, depending on the number there's a message, kind of fortune cookies, but if the user enters a word it needs to say "You typed a word, we need a number", as well as if it is a negative number it will say  "negative numbers won't work here"

I know how to do everything but I still can't figure out how to display this part

```
let number = +prompt("choose a number for good luck")

if (number ===NaN){
document.getElementById("fortuneOutput").innerHTML = "You typed a word, we need a number" 
}
else if (number < 0){
document.getElementById("fortuneOutput").innerHTML = "negative numbers won't work here"
}
```

but none of them work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652319/how-do-you-check-that-a-number-is-nan-in-javascript

Comment: What is number? How is it defined? You should show more code.

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), preferably as a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Comment: Your code should work if you use `parseInt()` to convert the user input to a number.

Comment: @Barmar the `+` will [convert to a number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus).

Comment: @Phix That wasn't in the question when I posted my comment.

Comment: @Barmar good callout, I didn't see the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Use `isNaN()`, as `NaN` is never equal to `NaN`.

Also, `parseInt()` makes strings to ints/numbers.