# Why does my if-else statement in js not work

Tags: javascript, if-statement

So basically, I was making a Geometrical Calculator. I realized that there was a way to make the code not run correctly, so I tried replacing that with an error message through an if-else statement. It did not work. Does anyone know the problem here?

The code that doesn't work is:

```
if (variable === NaN) {
        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Error. Please reload the page and try again";
} else {
        area = rounded(area formula, rounder);

        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Area of shape = formula = " + " = " + "<font color='red'>" + area + "</font>" + " (" + rounder + " d.p.)";
    }
```

Here is my code:
index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Geometrical Calculator </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1> Geometrical Calculator </h1>

        <br>

        <p id="display"> </p>

        <br>

        <button type="button" onclick="keyArea();" class="button"> Area </button>
        <button type="button" onclick="keyPerimeter();" class="button"> Perimeter </button>
        <button type="button" onclick="keyVolume();" class="button"> Volume </button>
        <button type="button" onclick="keySA();" class="button"> Surface Area </button>

        <br> <br>

        <button type="button" onclick="location.reload();" class="button"> AC </button>
        <button type="button" onclick="keyRound();" class="button"> Round </button>

        <br> <br> <br>

        <button type="button" onclick="keyAreaCircle();" class="button2" id="circle"> Circle </button>
        <button type="button" onclick="keyPerimeterCircle();" class="button2" id="circleP"> Circle </button>
        <button type="button" onclick="keyVolumeCylinder();" class="button2" id="cylinder"> Cylinder </button>
        <button type="button" onclick="keySACylinder();" class="button2" id="cylinderSA"> Cylinder </button>

        <br>

        <button type="button" onclick="keyAreaRectangle();" class="button2" id="rectangle"> Rectangle </button>
        <button type="button" onclick="keyPerimeterRectangle();" class="button2" id="rectangleP"> Rectangle </button>
        <button type="button" onclick="keyVolumeCuboid();" class="button2" id="cuboid"> Cuboid </button>
        <button type="button" onclick="keySACuboid();" class="button2" id="cuboidSA"> Cuboid </button>

        <br>

        <button type="button" onclick="keyAreaSquare();" class="button2" id="square"> Square </button>
        <button type="button" onclick="keyPerimeterSquare();" class="button2" id="squareP"> Square </button>
        <button type="button" onclick="keyVolumeCube();" class="button2" id="cube"> Cube </button>
        <button type="button" onclick="keySACube();" class="button2" id="cubeSA"> Cube </button>

        <br>

        <button type="button" onclick="keyAreaTriangle();" class="button2" id="triangle"> Triangle </button>
        <button type="button" onclick="keyVolumePyramid();" class="button2" id="pyramid"> Pyramid </button>

        <br>

        <button type="button" onclick="keyAreaParallelogram();" class="button2" id="parallelogram"> Parallelogram </button>
        <button type="button" onclick="keyVolumePrism();" class="button2" id="prism"> Prism </button>

        <br>

        <button type="button" onclick="keyAreaTrapezium();" class="button2" id="trapezium"> Trapezium </button>

        <script src="./index.js"> </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

style.css:

```
body {
    background-color: black;
}

h1 {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

.button {
    font-size: 175%;
    background-color: gray;
}
.button:hover {
    color: darkred;
}

.button2 {
    font-size: 150%;
    background-color: lightslategray;
}
.button2:hover {
    color: darkgreen;
}

#display {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 150%;
}
```

index.js:

```
let circle = document.getElementById("circle");
let rectangle = document.getElementById("rectangle");
let square = document.getElementById("square");
let triangle = document.getElementById("triangle");
let parallelogram = document.getElementById("parallelogram");
let trapezium = document.getElementById("trapezium");

let circleP = document.getElementById("circleP");
let rectangleP = document.getElementById("rectangleP");
let squareP = document.getElementById("squareP");

let cylinder = document.getElementById("cylinder");
let cuboid = document.getElementById("cuboid");
let cube = document.getElementById("cube");
let pyramid = document.getElementById("pyramid");
let prism = document.getElementById("prism");

let cylinderSA = document.getElementById("cylinderSA");
let cuboidSA = document.getElementById("cuboidSA");
let cubeSA = document.getElementById("cubeSA");

let buttonClickSound = new Audio("./Button Click Sound.mp3");

let radius;
const pi = Math.PI;
let length;
let width;
let side;
let height;
let base;
let topLength;
let bottom;
let cross_section;

let area;
let perimeter;
let volume;
let sa;

let rounder;

window.onload = windowLoad();

function windowLoad() {
    circle.style.display = "none";
    rectangle.style.display = "none";
    square.style.display = "none";
    triangle.style.display = "none";
    parallelogram.style.display = "none";
    trapezium.style.display = "none";

    circleP.style.display = "none";
    rectangleP.style.display = "none";
    squareP.style.display = "none";

    cylinder.style.display = "none";
    cuboid.style.display = "none";
    cube.style.display = "none";
    pyramid.style.display = "none";
    prism.style.display = "none";

    cylinderSA.style.display = "none";
    cuboidSA.style.display = "none";
    cubeSA.style.display = "none";

    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Answer";

    radius = null;
    length = null;
    width = null;
    area = null;
    side = null;
    height = null;
    base = null;
    topLength = null;
    bottom = null;
    perimeter = null;
    volume = null;
    cross_section = null;
    sa = null;

    rounder = 2;
}

function keyArea() {
    buttonClickSound.play();

    circleP.style.display = "none";
    rectangleP.style.display = "none";
    squareP.style.display = "none";

    cylinder.style.display = "none";
    cuboid.style.display = "none";
    cube.style.display = "none";
    pyramid.style.display = "none";
    prism.style.display = "none";

    cylinderSA.style.display = "none";
    cuboidSA.style.display = "none";
    cubeSA.style.display = "none";

    if (circle.style.display === "none") {
        circle.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        circle.style.display = "none";
    }

    if (rectangle.style.display === "none") {
        rectangle.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        rectangle.style.display = "none";
    }

    if (square.style.display === "none") {
        square.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        square.style.display = "none";
    }

    if (triangle.style.display === "none") {
        triangle.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        triangle.style.display = "none";
    }

    if (parallelogram.style.display === "none") {
        parallelogram.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        parallelogram.style.display = "none";
    }

    if (trapezium.style.display === "none") {
        trapezium.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        trapezium.style.display = "none";
    }
}
function keyPerimeter() {
    buttonClickSound.play();

    circle.style.display = "none";
    rectangle.style.display = "none";
    square.style.display = "none";
    triangle.style.display = "none";
    parallelogram.style.display = "none";
    trapezium.style.display = "none";

    cylinder.style.display = "none";
    cuboid.style.display = "none";
    cube.style.display = "none";
    pyramid.style.display = "none";
    prism.style.display = "none";

    cylinderSA.style.display = "none";
    cuboidSA.style.display = "none";
    cubeSA.style.display = "none";

    if (circleP.style.display === "none") {
        circleP.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        circleP.style.display = "none";
    }

    if (rectangleP.style.display === "none") {
        rectangleP.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        rectangleP.style.display = "none";
    }

    if (squareP.style.display === "none") {
        squareP.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        squareP.style.display = "none";
    }
}
function keyVolume() {
    buttonClickSound.play();

    circle.style.display = "none";
    rectangle.style.display = "none";
    square.style.display = "none";
    triangle.style.display = "none";
    parallelogram.style.display = "none";
    trapezium.style.display = "none";

    circleP.style.display = "none";
    rectangleP.style.display = "none";
    squareP.style.display = "none";

    cylinderSA.style.display = "none";
    cuboidSA.style.display = "none";
    cubeSA.style.display = "none";

    if (cylinder.style.display === "none") {
        cylinder.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        cylinder.style.display = "none";
    }

    if (cuboid.style.display === "none") {
        cuboid.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        cuboid.style.display = "none";
    }

    if (cube.style.display === "none") {
        cube.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        cube.style.display = "none";
    }

    if (pyramid.style.display === "none") {
        pyramid.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        pyramid.style.display = "none";
    }

    if (prism.style.display === "none") {
        prism.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        prism.style.display = "none";
    }
}
function keySA() {
    buttonClickSound.play();

    circle.style.display = "none";
    rectangle.style.display = "none";
    square.style.display = "none";
    triangle.style.display = "none";
    parallelogram.style.display = "none";
    trapezium.style.display = "none";

    circleP.style.display = "none";
    rectangleP.style.display = "none";
    squareP.style.display = "none";

    cylinder.style.display = "none";
    cuboid.style.display = "none";
    cube.style.display = "none";
    pyramid.style.display = "none";
    prism.style.display = "none";

    if (cylinderSA.style.display === "none") {
        cylinderSA.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        cylinderSA.style.display = "none";
    }

    if (cuboidSA.style.display === "none") {
        cuboidSA.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        cuboidSA.style.display = "none";
    }

    if (cubeSA.style.display === "none") {
        cubeSA.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        cubeSA.style.display = "none";
    }
}

function keyAreaCircle() {
    buttonClickSound.play();

    radius = parseFloat(prompt("Enter the radius of the circle"));

    if (radius === NaN) {
        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Error. Please reload the page and try again";
    } else {
        area = rounded(pi * (radius ** 2), rounder);

        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Area of circle = \u03C0r^2 = " + pi + " * " + radius + "^2 = " + "<font color='red'>" + area + "</font>" + " (" + rounder + " d.p.)";
    }
}
function keyAreaRectangle() {
    buttonClickSound.play();
    
    length = parseFloat(prompt("Enter the length of the rectangle"));
    width = parseFloat(prompt("Enter the width of the rectangle"));

    if (length === NaN || width === NaN) {
        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Error. Please reload the page and try again";
    } else {
        area = rounded(length * width, rounder);

        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Area of rectangle = lw = " + length + " * " + width + " = " + "<font color='red'>" + area + "</font>" + " (" + rounder + " d.p.)";
    }
}
function keyAreaSquare() {
    buttonClickSound.play();

    side = parseFloat(prompt("Enter the side of the square"));

    if (side === NaN) {
        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Error. Please reload the page and try again";
    } else {
        area = rounded(side ** 2, rounder);

        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Area of square = s^2 = " + side + "^2 = " + "<font color='red'>" + area + "</font>" + " (" + rounder + " d.p.)";
    }
}
function keyAreaTriangle() {
    buttonClickSound.play();

    height = parseFloat(prompt("Enter the height of the triangle"));
    base = parseFloat(prompt("Enter the base of the triangle"));

    if (height === NaN || base === NaN) {
        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Error. Please reload the page and try again";
    } else {
        area = rounded(0.5 * height * base, rounder);

        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Area of triangle = 0.5bh = 0.5 * " + base + " * " + height + " = " + "<font color='red'>" + area + "</font>" + " (" + rounder + " d.p.)";
    }
}
function keyAreaParallelogram() {
    buttonClickSound.play();

    height = parseFloat(prompt("Enter the height of the parallelogram"));
    base = parseFloat(prompt("Enter the base of the parallelogram"));

    if (height === NaN || base === NaN) {
        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Error. Please reload the page and try again";
    } else {
        area = rounded(height * base, rounder);

        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Area of parallelogram = bh = " + base + " * " + height + " = " + "<font color='red'>" + area + "</font>" + " (" + rounder + " d.p.)";
    }
}
function keyAreaTrapezium() {
    buttonClickSound.play();

    topLength = parseFloat(prompt("Enter the top length of the trapezium (a)"));
    bottom = parseFloat(prompt("Enter the bottom length of the trapezium (b)"));
    height = parseFloat(prompt("Enter the height of the trapezium"));

    if (topLength === NaN || bottom === NaN || height === NaN) {
        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Error. Please reload the page and try again";
    } else {
        area = rounded(0.5 * height * (topLength + bottom), rounder);

        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Area of trapezium = 0.5h(a+b) = 0.5 * " + height + "(" + topLength + " + " + bottom + ") = " + "<font color='red'>" + area + "</font>" + " (" + rounder + " d.p.)";
    }


}

function keyPerimeterCircle() {
    buttonClickSound.play();

    radius = parseFloat(prompt("Enter the radius of the circle"));

    if (radius === NaN) {
        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Error. Please reload the page and try again";
    } else {
        perimeter = rounded(2 * pi * radius, rounder);

        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Circumference of circle = 2\u03C0r = " + "2 * " + pi + " * " + radius + " = " + "<font color='red'>" + perimeter + "</font>" + " (" + rounder + " d.p.)";
    }
}
function keyPerimeterRectangle() {
    buttonClickSound.play();

    length = parseFloat(prompt("Enter the length of the rectangle"));
    width = parseFloat(prompt("Enter the width of the rectangle"));

    if (length === NaN || width === NaN) {
        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Error. Please reload the page and try again";
    } else {
        perimeter = rounded(2 * (length + width), rounder);

        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Perimeter of rectangle = 2(l+w) = 2(" + length + "+" + width + ") = " + "<font color='red'>" + perimeter + "</font>" + " (" + rounder + " d.p.)";
    }
}
function keyPerimeterSquare() {
    buttonClickSound.play();

    side = parseFloat(prompt("Enter the side of the square"));

    if (side === NaN) {
        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Error. Please reload the page and try again";
    } else {
        perimeter = rounded(4 * side, rounder);

        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Perimeter of square = 4s = 4 * " + side + " = " + "<font color='red'>" + perimeter + "</font>" + " (" + rounder + " d.p.)";
    }
}

function keyVolumeCylinder() {
    buttonClickSound.play();

    radius = parseFloat(prompt("Enter the radius of the cylinder"));
    height = parseFloat(prompt("Enter the height of the cylinder"));

    if (radius === NaN || height === NaN) {
        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Error. Please reload the page and try again";
    } else {
        volume = rounded(pi * (radius ** 2) * height, rounder);

        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Volume of cylinder = \u03C0r^2h = " + pi + " * " + radius + "^2" + " * " + height + " = " + "<font color='red'>" + volume + "</font>" + " (" + rounder + " d.p.)";
    }
}
function keyVolumeCuboid() {
    buttonClickSound.play();

    length = parseFloat(prompt("Enter the length of the cuboid"));
    width = parseFloat(prompt("Enter the width of the cuboid"));
    height = parseFloat(prompt("Enter the height of the cuboid"));

    if (length === NaN || width === NaN || height === NaN) {
        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Error. Please reload the page and try again";
    }  else {
        volume = rounded(length * width * height, rounder);

        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Volume of cuboid = lwh = " + length + " * " + width + " * " + height + " = " + "<font color='red'>" + volume + "</font>" + " (" + rounder + " d.p.)";
    }
}
function keyVolumeCube() {
    buttonClickSound.play();

    side = parseFloat(prompt("Enter the side of the cube"));

    if (side === NaN) {
        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Error. Please reload the page and try again";
    } else {
        volume = rounded(side ** 3, rounder);

        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Volume of cube = s^3 = " + side + "^3 = " + "<font color='red'>" + volume + "</font>" + " (" + rounder + " d.p.)";
    }
}
function keyVolumePyramid() {
    buttonClickSound.play();

    base = parseFloat(prompt("Enter the base area of the pyramid"));
    height = parseFloat(prompt("Enter the height of the pyramid"));

    if (base === NaN || height === NaN) {
        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Error. Please reload the page and try again";
    } else {
        volume = rounded((1/3) * base * height, rounder);

        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Volume of pyramid = bh/3 = " + base + " * " + height + " / 3 = " + "<font color='red'>" + volume + "</font>" + " (" + rounder + " d.p.)";
    }
}
function keyVolumePrism() {
    buttonClickSound.play();

    cross_section = parseFloat(prompt("Enter the area of the cross-section of the prism (could be the area of any shape)"));
    length = parseFloat(prompt("Enter the length of the prism"));

    if (cross_section === NaN || length === NaN) {
        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Error. Please reload the page and try again";
    } else {
        volume = rounded(cross_section * length, rounder);

        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Volume of prism = area of cross-section * l = " + cross_section + " * " + length + " = " + "<font color='red'>" + volume + "</font>" + " (" + rounder + " d.p.)";
    }
}

function keySACylinder() {
    buttonClickSound.play();

    radius = parseFloat(prompt("Enter the radius of the cylinder"));
    height = parseFloat(prompt("Enter the height of the cylinder"));

    if (radius === NaN || height === NaN) {
        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Error. Please reload the page and try again";
    } else {
        sa = rounded(((2 * pi * (radius ** 2)) + (2 * pi * radius * height)), rounder);

        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Surface Area of cylinder = (2\u03C0r^2) + (2\u03C0rh) = (2 * " + pi + " * " + radius + "^2) + (2 * " + pi + " * " + radius + " * " + height + ") = " + "<font color='red'>" + sa + "</font>" + " (" + rounder + " d.p.)";
    }
}
function keySACuboid() {
    buttonClickSound.play();

    length = parseFloat(prompt("Enter the length of the cuboid"));
    width = parseFloat(prompt("Enter the width of the cuboid"));
    height = parseFloat(prompt("Enter the height of the cuboid"));

    if (length === NaN || width === NaN || height === NaN) {
        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Error. Please reload the page and try again";
    } else {
        sa = rounded(2 * ((length * width) + (width * height) + (length * height)), rounder);

        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Surface Area of cuboid = 2((lw) + (wh) + (lh)) = 2(" + length + " * " + width + ") + (" + width + " * " + height + ") + (" + length + " * " + height + ") = " + "<font color='red'>" + sa + "</font>" + " (" + rounder + " d.p.)";
    }
}
function keySACube() {
    buttonClickSound.play();

    side = parseFloat(prompt("Enter the side of the cube"));

    if (side === NaN) {
        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Error. Please reload the page and try again";
    } else {
        sa = rounded(6 * (side ** 2), rounder);

        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Surface Area of cube = 6s^2 = 6 * " + side + "^2 = " + "<font color='red'>" + sa + "</font>" + " (" + rounder + " d.p.)";
    }
}

function keyRound() {
    buttonClickSound.play();

    rounder = parseInt(prompt("Enter the number of decimal places the answer should be rounded to. Default: 14"));

    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Round = " + rounder + " decimal places";
}
function rounded(number, decimal) {
    decimal = Math.pow(10, decimal);
    return Math.round(number * decimal) / decimal;
}
```

Comment: Be aware that `(NaN === NaN)` is false

Comment: the problem is that `NaN !== NaN` .... use `isNaN` to test for `NaN` equality

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565164/what-is-the-rationale-for-all-comparisons-returning-false-for-ieee754-nan-values and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652319/how-do-you-check-that-a-number-is-nan-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

The value of `NaN === NaN` is `false`. You simply can't compare two NaN's together. Imagine a case where one of them is `0/0` and one of them is `parseInt("some random text here!")`, while they both evaluate to `NaN` they shouldn't considered equal.
So I suggest using `isNaN()` method instead.