# JS Function for seeking the biggest number in array fails when the first element is undefined or NaN

Tags: javascript

I have the following function:

```js
const biggestNumOfArray = (array) => {
  if (Array.isArray(array)) {
    let biggest = array[0];
    for (i=0; i < array.length; i++) {
      if (array[i] > biggest) {
        biggest = array[i];
      }
    }
    return biggest;
  } else {
    return NaN;
  }
}
```

It's purpose is to output the biggest number in an array, ignoring non-number values, and return NaN if it isn't an array.

However, consider the following array:

```js
let myArray = [undefined, 8, 74, -22, 269.64, 92];
```

All of a sudden, it outputs not `269.64`, but `undefined`.

See, if the first element in an array is `undefined` or `NaN`, the variable `biggest` gets stuck on it, as `number > NaN` and `number > undefined` on line 5 will always be false, which means the line to change the `biggest` to the current will never be executed. How do I avoid that?

Note that this doesn't happen with `undefined`s that aren't first, as `number > undefined` also outputs false, unallowing to change the `biggest` to it.

I tried to change the check for the number being the current biggest, by changing it to `array[i] > biggest && array[i] != null`, using abstract equality to check for it being `undefined` or `null`, but it didn't work - I still got back `undefined`. It also wouldn't cover `NaN`.

Comment: so check if it is a number. null is not undefined...

Comment: ill try to add && !isNaN

Comment: @epascarello `array[i] > biggest && !(isNaN(array[i]))` doesnt work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652319/how-do-you-check-that-a-number-is-nan-in-javascript

Comment: instead if `let biggest = array[0];` as its initial value you should do something like `let biggest = 0;` or something like that, assuming that you have at least one positive element in your array

Comment: You could do `let biggest = array[0] || 0;`

Comment: You are going to have to change your check for array[0] so that is a number...

Comment: `let biggest === -Infinity`

Comment: @Kinglish array[0] || 0 works, thanks. except if the first element is undefined and all numbers in the array are less than 0. fix that and you can post it as an answer. also explain how it works.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli your answer works, post it as an answer. except you need one "=" and not 3.

Comment: No `|| 0` is wrong... bad assumption that all the numbers are positive... lol

Comment: @epascarello Negative numbers are truthy too...

Comment: @danik0011 Are you asking about why _your_ function is not working, or just how to do this?

Comment: If you want a simple method of just doing it, `Math.max(...array.filter((v) => v != null && !isNaN(v)))` should work.

Comment: i know that Math.max exists but i decided to not use it :D

Comment: So... this is a self-challenge and you need/needed help fixing a bug in your code?

Comment: @DarrylNoakes Yes but 0 is greater than -100 `let myArray = [undefined, -8, -74, -22, -269.64, -92];` so what would the result be if you set it to zero?

Comment: Sorry, forgot it was being used as the starting value :facepalm:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@GabrielePetrioli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/128165/gabriele-petrioli) suggested to initially set `biggest` to -Infinity, which worked. Thanks.

I also got took an idea from [@nina-scholz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1447675/nina-scholz) to output NaN if `biggest` isn't a number in the end.

Here is the final fixed and working code:

```js
const biggestNumOfArray = (array) => {
  if(Array.isArray(array)){
    let biggest = -Infinity;
    for(i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
      if(array[i] > biggest) {
          biggest = array[i];
      }
    }
    return typeof(biggest) === 'number' ? biggest : NaN;
  } else { return NaN; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could check for finiteness ([`Number.isFinite`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isFinite)) and take only relevant values for checking the biggest value.

```js
const biggestNumOfArray = (array) => {
  let biggest = undefined;
  if (Array.isArray(array)) {
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      if (!Number.isFinite(array[i])) continue;
      if (biggest === undefined || array[i] > biggest) biggest = array[i];
    }
  }
  return isFinite(biggest) ? biggest : NaN;
};

const myArray = [undefined, 8, 74, -22, 269.64, 92];

console.log(biggestNumOfArray(myArray));
```

Comment: i already found `let biggest = -Infinity` to work for me, but i'll take the `isFinite` and a dd it to the code.

Comment: @danik0011 what if all the numbers are undefined? The max would be `-Infinity` :) Got to love edge cases. lol

Comment: lol wait does `isFinite(-Infinity)` return true?

Comment: then ill use `typeof biggest = 'number'`

Comment: No; `isFinite(Infinity)`, `isFinite(-Infinity)`, and `isFinite(undefined)` all return `false`. However, `isFinite(null)` returns `true`.

Comment: Note also that `null` is equivalent to `0` when comparing using "greater than" and co. Comparisons with `undefined` are always false.

Comment: Hey, neat! I didn't know the global function(s) and the one(s) on Number were different.

Answer (score 2):

A simpler method would be to use `Array#filter` to get rid of non-numeric values, then use spread syntax to pass the rest of the values as separate arguments to `Math.max`.

```js
const biggestNumOfArray = arr => Array.isArray(arr) ? 
  Math.max(...arr.filter(x => !isNaN(x))) : NaN;

console.log(biggestNumOfArray([undefined, 8, 74, -22, 269.64, 92]));
```

Comment: i know but i decided to do it without Math.max, as a challenge :D

Answer (score 0):

```js
//Nullish coalescing operator
const biggestNumOfArray = (array) => {
  if (Array.isArray(array)) {
    let biggest = array[0] ?? 0;
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      if (array[i] > biggest) {
        biggest = array[i];
      }
    }
    return biggest;
  } else {
    return NaN;
  }
}
let myArray = [undefined, 8, 74, -22, 269.64, 92];

console.log(biggestNumOfArray(myArray));
```

Comment: Bad assumption that all the numbers in my array are bigger than 0. You can put -Infinity there instead. Thanks for the answer, but i decided to just initially set biggest to -Infinity anyway.