# Delete the key which contains empty object inside an array using javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to delete the JSON key which contains empty object inside an array...
This is my **JSON** structure:

```
{
    "CreateSubnet": {
        "description": "Creatingasubnet.",
        "input": {
            "body": {
                "subnet": {
                    "network_id": "sdfsdfds",
                    "ip_version": "sdfdsfs",
                    "cidr": "sdfsdf",
                    "allocation_pools": [
                        {}
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "action": "neutron.create_network",
        "publish": {},
        "on-success": []
    }
}
```

Please help me to delete the element `"allocation_pools"`..
I never want this key and this value ...

The **expected output JSON** will be look like...

```
{
    "CreateSubnet": {
        "description": "Creatingasubnet.",
        "input": {
            "body": {
                "subnet": {
                    "network_id": "sdfsdfds",
                    "ip_version": "sdfdsfs",
                    "cidr": "sdfsdf"
                }
            }
        },
        "action": "neutron.create_network",
        "publish": {},
        "on-success": []
    }
}
```

Note this JSON is from external source it changes dynamically...
So please tell me how to validate the JSON key contains Array...
if yes , Check whether it has empty object or not ....
This is my question

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I remove all null and empty string values from a json object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23774231/how-do-i-remove-all-null-and-empty-string-values-from-a-json-object)

Answer (score -1):

Use the `delete` operator to remove the property.

```js
var obj = {
    "CreateSubnet": {
        "description": "Creatingasubnet.",
        "input": {
            "body": {
                "subnet": {
                    "network_id": "sdfsdfds",
                    "ip_version": "sdfdsfs",
                    "cidr": "sdfsdf",
                    "allocation_pools": [
                        {}
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "action": "neutron.create_network",
        "publish": {},
        "on-success": []
    }
}
delete (obj.CreateSubnet.input.body.subnet.allocation_pools);
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(obj)
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```