# How to remove the null value in json string using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to remove the null value in json string using jquery

`var jsonstring=[null,null,{"rank":"23","credit":"10"},null,null,{"rank":"26","credit":"10"},null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,{"rank":"31","credit":"05"}]`

Comment: unjson, remove null, json again?

Comment: javascript solution to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/281264/remove-empty-elements-from-an-array-in-javascript

Comment: You can try this on:-
jsonstring=JSON.stringify(jsonstring).replace(/null/g,' ');
jsonstring.replace(/ ,/g,'')

Comment: Please give the example for my jsonstring

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var arr = JSON.parse(json_string);
arr = arr.filter(function(n){ return n }); 
json_string = JSON.stringify(arr)
```

Comment: Please give the example for my jsonstring

Comment: just replace json_string with your actual JSON string

Answer (score 2):

Use like this

```
(function filter(obj) {
    $.each(obj, function(key, value){
        if (value === "" || value === null){
            delete obj[key];
        } else if (Object.prototype.toString.call(value) === '[object Object]') {
            filter(value);
        } else if ($.isArray(value)) {
            $.each(value, function (k,v) { filter(v); });
        }
    });
})(sjonObj);
```

Comment: Copied from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23774231/how-do-i-remove-all-null-and-empty-string-values-from-a-json-object)? Change variable name atleast! :P

Comment: Please give the example for my jsonstring

Answer (score 1):

You should use array access notation please see the below code

```
    delete sjonObj[key];


 $.each(sjonObj, function(key, value){
 if (value === "" || value === null){
    delete sjonObj[key];
  }
 });
```

Thanks

Comment: Please give the example for my jsonstring

Comment: you have the input json string with you rite?