# Remove object with null attributes in json using jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

How can I remove objects with null attributes? For example:

```
{  
   "login":"user.test",
   "dateTime":"02/07/2015 16:51",
   "action":"Update",
   "inner":{  
      "id":32,
      "name":"asdkjh",
      "other":"asdk",
      "document":"21321",
      "address":{  
         "zip":{  

         }
      },
      "email":{  

      }
   }
}
```

When I call `writeValueAsString` Jackson must ignore objects with null attributes, in this case address, zip and e-mail. Is it possible with some feature?
Using `setSerializationInclusion(Inclusion.NON_EMPTY)` null values were ignored but the inner objects still there.

Comment: Those aren't null values.

Comment: Sorry. I edited the question. Consider null attributes not null values.

Comment: There's nothing _null_ in what you posted.

Comment: Show us your POJO types.

Comment: Possible answers in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23774231/how-do-i-remove-all-null-and-empty-string-values-from-a-json-object

Comment: This is because I used setSerializationInclusion(Inclusion.NON_EMPTY). Now I want to remove the objects.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @goldenratio but in this link the objects are removed manually. Jackson doesn't provide any feature for this?