# Combining 2 similar JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, underscore.js

My aim is to combine 2 similar JSON objects so that the output will have its value taken from the json objects supplied. For eg:

```
var obj1 = {'name': 'xyz', 'age':''}, obj2 = {'name':'', 'age':'66'}
//would like to have some functionality like below that gives me the output
obj3 = combine(obj1,obj2) 
//desired output below.
obj3 = {'name': 'xyz', 'age':'66'}
```

Comment: `obj2 = {name:'': age:'66'}` is invalid json format

Comment: If you decide to post something on SO make sure it's formatted correctly first. Downvoted until you do so.

Comment: @Mayank Pandeyz You should apologize OP for that misleading code which you have fortunately already deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you say the two objects are similar I am going to assume that this means **for those keys which are common among the two objects one has data and other has ''.**

The second assumption I am going to make is that **for any keys not common to both the objects you want it to be copied as is to the new object.**

```
var obj1 = {'a': 'b', 'c': ''};
var obj2 = {'a': '', 'c': 'd', 'e': 'f'};
var obj3 = {};
var key;

for (key in obj1) {
    if(obj1[key] === '') {
        obj3[key] = obj2[key];
    } else {
        obj3[key] = obj1[key];
    }
}

for(key in obj2) {
    if(!(key in obj3)) {
        obj3[key] = obj2[key];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you added the jQuery tag, I assume you are using it. If so, you can use jQuery's `$.extend` method.

```
var obj1 = {'name': 'xyz', 'age':''},
    obj2 = {'name':'', 'age':'66'},
    obj3 = $.extend(obj1,obj2);
```

Comment: I tried $.extend , but that won't give the desired output

Comment: You are correct. For it to work, you can't have empty properties. Try deleting all of them beforehand like suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23774231/how-do-i-remove-all-null-and-empty-string-values-from-a-json-object

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure about what the disired result is, but this code should point you in the right direction. It copies values from obj2 to obj1, if the value has a value (with isnt empty or false):

```
combine = function(a, b) {
 var bKeys = Object.keys(b)
 for (var i = 0; i < bKeys.length; i++) {
   var key = bKeys[i]
   if (b[key]) {
     a[key] = b[key]
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Martin for your effort. I will check it and respond.