# ignore null values while deserializing JSON in newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have following json coming from server

```
{
 "contactList":[{

      "contactName":"Jhon",
      "address":null,
      "phone":null,
      "contactId":99932

}]

}
```

now when i am deserializing using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(content)` i want following output

```
{
     "contactList":[{

          "contactName":"Jhon",
          "contactId":99932

    }]

    }
```

i tried following code but its not working

```
 JsonSerializerSettings jsonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
                    {
                        NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
                        MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore
                    };
```

this is my Contact model

```
public class Contact 
    {
        [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public String address { set; get; }

       [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
         public String phone { set; get; }

        [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
         public String name { set; get; }

        [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
         public String id { set; get; }
  }
```

model of Response

```
     [JsonObject(MemberSerialization = MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
 public class Response 
    {
         [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public IList<SignodeMSA.Model.Master.Contact> contactsList { get; }
  }
```

and i am deserializing after fetching it from server

```
  Response responseData = await Task.Run(() => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(content, jsonSettings));
```

Comment: The json settings must work, how do you use them? Post the code where you serialize the data.

Comment: @SiyavashHamdi Json.net has the ability to not to write out null values if its told to do so.

Comment: The jsonSettings  is correct, maybe it is not being used.

Comment: updated the question

Comment: What's the `Response` type definition?

Comment: You are *deserializing* to the statically typed `Contact` which has properties `phone` and `id` those are part of your .NET class. They can't disappear. `NullValueHandling.Ignore` affects *serialization* only.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need manually delete that properties from json string.

Maybe like this : [How do I remove all null and empty string values from a json object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23774231/how-do-i-remove-all-null-and-empty-string-values-from-a-json-object)