# JSON editor to clean up dataset

Tags: json, editor

I have a JSON data set with around 10,000 objects that each hold around 20 data items.

Since some data items are empty, I'd like to filter and clean up the data set, i.e. delete all data items that are empty.

Is there a good JSON editor that someone can recommend? Or if there is another way to clean up the file? I am on a Mac and rather not use an online editor.

Comment: Why dont you write simple python/javascript script to remove it. Doing filtering of 10000 objects from JSON editor will be huge task

Comment: Yes that seems the most logical. Which environment/software would you recommend doing that? I do know a bit of javascript but no experience working with writing/manipulating JSON files. Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45310279/removing-empty-entry-from-json-or-object
Try this, if you still have issues, let me know here.

Answer (score 0):

Pyhon or javascript is way to go.

If you still want to do it manually you can use this json editor which support json up to 100k lines -

https://www.codetools.ninja/jsoneditor

- Copy paste your json
- click on Format Json
- click on search / replace on top right corner
- In find text field put the key:value combo "TobeDeleted":"",
- Keep replace field empty
- Hit replaceAll button