# Javascript: removing elements from Json by value

Tags: javascript, json

I need to remove elements from a json string returned by an AJAX call.

I'm not sure how to loop through the string and remove all elements where the value i NULL.

My json looks like this.

```
[
 {"ID":"27","Agility":"15","Balance":null,"Strength":"37","Physiology":"32"},
 {"ID":"30","Agility":"27","Balance":null,"Strength":null,"Physiology":null},
 {"ID":"34","Agility":null,"Balance":null,"Strength":null,"Physiology":null},
 {"ID":"36","Agility":null,"Balance":null,"Strength":null,"Physiology":null},
 {"ID":"40","Agility":null,"Balance":"20","Strength":null,"Physiology":"34"},
 {"ID":"42","Agility":null,"Balance":"16","Strength":null,"Physiology":null},
 {"ID":"51","Agility":null,"Balance":null,"Strength":"39","Physiology":null}
]
```

I thought I might do something like this for every key but i would prefer a generic function:

```
if(json[index].Strength == null){
    json.splice(index,1);
}
```

Comment: So you want to remove the object if any of its keys is `null` ?

Comment: try this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23774231/how-do-i-remove-all-null-and-empty-string-values-from-a-json-object

Comment: `generic function`?

Comment: That was the idea.
if it was not possible I would go with a line for every key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse json with `JSON.parse` method and then use `filter()` method on that array.

```js
const json = '[{"ID":"27","Agility":"15","Balance":null,"Strength":"37","Physiology":"32"},{"ID":"30","Agility":"27","Balance":null,"Strength":null,"Physiology":null},{"ID":"34","Agility":null,"Balance":null,"Strength":null,"Physiology":null},{"ID":"36","Agility":null,"Balance":null,"Strength":null,"Physiology":null},{"ID":"40","Agility":null,"Balance":"20","Strength":null,"Physiology":"34"},{"ID":"42","Agility":null,"Balance":"16","Strength":null,"Physiology":null},{"ID":"51","Agility":null,"Balance":null,"Strength":"39","Physiology":null}]'

const data = JSON.parse(json).filter(o => o.Strength != null)
console.log(data)
```

If you want to remove elements where some property has value of `null` you can use `some` method inside `filter`.

```js
const json = '[{"ID":"27","Agility":"15","Balance":null,"Strength":"37","Physiology":"32"},{"ID":"30","Agility":"27","Balance":null,"Strength":null,"Physiology":null},{"ID":"34","Agility":null,"Balance":null,"Strength":null,"Physiology":null},{"ID":"36","Agility":null,"Balance":null,"Strength":null,"Physiology":null},{"ID":"40","Agility":null,"Balance":"20","Strength":null,"Physiology":"34"},{"ID":"42","Agility":null,"Balance":"16","Strength":null,"Physiology":null},{"ID":"51","Agility":null,"Balance":null,"Strength":"39","Physiology":null}]'

const data = JSON.parse(json).filter(o => {
  return !Object.keys(o).some(k => o[k] == null)
})
console.log(data)
```

Comment: Hi Nenad.

Thank you for your suggestions.
They works fine but I think that I did not explain myself enough.  :(

I wanted to remove all entries with the value of null but keep the rest of the entries.

So: {"ID":"30","Agility":"27","Balance":null,"Strength":null,"Physiology":null}

Would be reduced to:
{"ID":"30","Agility":"27"}

My apologies for the unclear explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Use `filter`:

```
const newJson = json.filter(item => item.Strength !== null)
```

Answer (score 1):

> If you prefer a generic function, **Lodash** is the best option.
>
> *PickBy* picks up properties from an object, based on a Predicate.
> Here predicate is *Identity*, which means, pickup non null properties from the object.

```js
var jsonResponse = '[{"ID":"27","Agility":"15","Balance":null,"Strength":"37","Physiology":"32"},{"ID":"30","Agility":"27","Balance":null,"Strength":null,"Physiology":null},{"ID":"34","Agility":null,"Balance":null,"Strength":null,"Physiology":null},{"ID":"36","Agility":null,"Balance":null,"Strength":null,"Physiology":null},{"ID":"40","Agility":null,"Balance":"20","Strength":null,"Physiology":"34"},{"ID":"42","Agility":null,"Balance":"16","Strength":null,"Physiology":null},{"ID":"51","Agility":null,"Balance":null,"Strength":"39","Physiology":null}]';

var responseArr = JSON.parse(jsonResponse);

// Only lines that matter
responseArr = _.map(responseArr, function(obj) {
  return _.pickBy(obj, _.identity);
});

console.log("Array of Objects: ", responseArr);
console.log("JSON: ", JSON.stringify(responseArr));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

> Put the above mentioned script tag just before closing  tag of your html page.
>
> So just loop through the whole array response using map, and apply *PickBy* on each object of the array, and you have yourself an array of sparse objects.

Comment: It seem what I'm looking for based on the code snippet but I get an error when using your code.

Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined

Comment: Oh, you have to use lodash for this to work

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>

**Dependencies are mentioned just above the Run code snippet button**

Answer (score 0):

Try Array [**filter()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method with [**ES6 Arrow**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) function.

**Demo**

```js
var jsonObj = [
 {"ID":"27","Agility":"15","Balance":null,"Strength":"37","Physiology":"32"},
 {"ID":"30","Agility":"27","Balance":null,"Strength":null,"Physiology":null},
 {"ID":"34","Agility":null,"Balance":null,"Strength":null,"Physiology":null},
 {"ID":"36","Agility":null,"Balance":null,"Strength":null,"Physiology":null},
 {"ID":"40","Agility":null,"Balance":"20","Strength":null,"Physiology":"34"},
 {"ID":"42","Agility":null,"Balance":"16","Strength":null,"Physiology":null},
 {"ID":"51","Agility":null,"Balance":null,"Strength":"39","Physiology":null}
];

var res = jsonObj.filter(elem => elem.Strength !== null);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: I get an error when using your code:

Uncaught TypeError: response.filter is not a function.
I can also see that PHPStorm gives an error in the code on the "=>".
It says "Expression Expected"

what am I missing ??

Comment: @FlemmingLemche I did not use any `response.filter` in my code then how it is possible to get error on that ? You can run the `code snippet` in my answer it is working fine .

Comment: I forgot to use .parseJSON before running your code.