# How to clear json object value as empty in javascript / JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

var myObj;

```
myObj = [{ "name":"John", "age":30, "car":"maruti" },{ "name":"Smith", "age":50, "car":"indica" }];
```

I want to get json

```
[{ "name":"", "age":, "car":"" },{ "name":"", "age":, "car":"" }];
```

please solve this problem

Comment: please show what you have already done to solve the problem

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23774231/how-do-i-remove-all-null-and-empty-string-values-from-a-json-object/23774287

Comment: Your output is not valid.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `map` and `for`

```js
var myObj = [{ "name":"John", "age":30, "car":"maruti" },{ "name":"Smith", "age":50, "car":"indica" }];

var result = myObj.map(v=>{
   v = Object.assign({}, v);
   for( let k in v ) v[k] = "";
   return v;
});
 
console.log( result );
```

---

Changing the age only.

```js
var myObj = [{ "name":"John", "age":30, "car":"maruti" },{ "name":"Smith", "age":50, "car":"indica" }];
 
var result = myObj.map(v=>{
   v = Object.assign({}, v);
   v.age = "";
   return v;
});

console.log( result );
```

Comment: ok fine. this code is successfully run in .html page. Actually I have already a .js page. When I write this code in my .js page the error occurred. this line is shown in red color. How to possible this code in .js page?

Comment: What is the error? You have to check if it is working or not. Dont rely on you notepad/IDE. Your IDE might not be updated. `map` is a new code, so i wast thinking your IDE is not updated.

Comment: My IDE version is IDE 8.0

Comment: Yes. it is successfully working in my browser (Mozila)
that is: like abc.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo1"></p><br/>
<br/><br/>
<p id="demo2"></p>
<script>
var myObj, x;
myObj = [{ "name":"John", "age":30, "car":"maruti" },{ "name":"Smith", "age":50, "car":"indica" }];   
 var result2=  myObj.map(x => Object.keys(x).reduce((total, value) => {
   total[value] = '';
   return total; 
   }, {}));

document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result2);
</script>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Is it working on Mozila when you put the code on .js?

Comment: yes. when I save this code in a .js file. and call from html file, then successfully working.

Comment: That is great. It means your IDE is just recognizing the map code. But this should work on browsers

Comment: No, in IDE 8.0 is not working. my .js file in IDE 8.0, When I paste this code in .js file then show red underline

Comment: Dont mind it. The ide just don’t recognize the code. As long as it works on a browser. It is fine

Comment: Do you help me another?
[{ "name":"John", "age":30, "car":"maruti" },{ "name":"Smith", "age":50, "car":"indica" }]
I want to get
[{ "name":"John", "age":, "car":"maruti" },{ "name":"Smith", "age":, "car":"indica" }]

Particular one value that is "age" is empty

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that won't change the original value:

```
myObj.map(x => Object.keys(x).reduce((total, value) => { total[value] = ''; return total; }, {}));
```

Comment: ok fine. this code is successfully run in .html page. Actually I have already a .js page. When I write this code in my .js page the error occurred. this line is shown in red color. How to possible this code in .js page?