# How to exclude empty values and keys in array with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax, object

I have an array;

```
[
  {pre_ref_fullname: "", pre_ref_position: "", pre_ref_phone: ""},
  {pre_ref_fullname: "", pre_ref_position: "", pre_ref_phone: ""},
  {pre_ref_fullname: "", pre_ref_position: "", pre_ref_phone: ""}
]
```

So, I want to remove elements if values is empty. If user added 2 referance info I want to get this data like this;

```
[
{pre_ref_fullname: "Name", pre_ref_position: "Job", pre_ref_phone: "Number"},
{pre_ref_fullname: "Name2", pre_ref_position: "Job2", pre_ref_phone: "Number2"}
]
```

I'm used some methods but not working. This is the last try with reduce and $prerefData is have this array;

```
var arr = $prerefData.reduce((result, item) => {
    if (item.value != "") {
       result.push(item);
    }
    return result;
    }, []);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: You mean empty all properties, right?

Comment: @Eddie yes all properties. Sorry for poor lang. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove all null and empty string values from a json object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23774231/how-do-i-remove-all-null-and-empty-string-values-from-a-json-object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Javascript Array filter method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp)

Briefly `Array.filter` will loop over your array, and run the callback on each element:

- If it returns **true**: Element is included in `result`
- If it returns **false**: Element is filtered out

```js
let data = [
  {pre_ref_fullname: "", pre_ref_position: "", pre_ref_phone: ""},
  {pre_ref_fullname: "", pre_ref_position: "", pre_ref_phone: ""},
  {pre_ref_fullname: "", pre_ref_position: "", pre_ref_phone: ""},
  {pre_ref_fullname: "Name", pre_ref_position: "Job", pre_ref_phone: "Number"},
  {pre_ref_fullname: "Name2", pre_ref_position: "Job2", pre_ref_phone: "Number2"}
];

let result = data.filter(function (item) {
  for(key in item) {
    if (item[key]) {
      // Means one of the object keys have values, include it in the result
      return true
    }
  }
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thank you Ali, It's exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @NoobDoez Glad I can help :)

Answer (score 1):

try

```
data.filter(x=> Object.values(x).join(''));
```

```js
let data = [
  {pre_ref_fullname: "", pre_ref_position: "", pre_ref_phone: ""},
  {pre_ref_fullname: "", pre_ref_position: "", pre_ref_phone: ""},
  {pre_ref_fullname: "", pre_ref_position: "", pre_ref_phone: ""},
  {pre_ref_fullname: "Name", pre_ref_position: "Job", pre_ref_phone: "Number"},
  {pre_ref_fullname: "Name2", pre_ref_position: "Job2", pre_ref_phone: "Number2"}
];

let r = data.filter(x=> Object.values(x).join(''));

console.log(r);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter`, use `Object.values` to extract all values of individual objects.use `every` to check if all array values are not empty strings.

```js
let data = [{"pre_ref_fullname":"","pre_ref_position":"","pre_ref_phone":""},{"pre_ref_fullname":"","pre_ref_position":"","pre_ref_phone":""},{"pre_ref_fullname":"","pre_ref_position":"","pre_ref_phone":""},{"pre_ref_fullname":"Name","pre_ref_position":"Job","pre_ref_phone":"Number"},{"pre_ref_fullname":"Name2","pre_ref_position":"Job2","pre_ref_phone":"Number2"}];

let result = data.filter(o => Object.values(o).every(e => e.trim() !== ""));

console.log(result);
```

You can use `some` if you want to check at least one is not an empty string.

```js
let data = [{"pre_ref_fullname":"","pre_ref_position":"","pre_ref_phone":""},{"pre_ref_fullname":"","pre_ref_position":"not Empty","pre_ref_phone":""},{"pre_ref_fullname":"","pre_ref_position":"","pre_ref_phone":""},{"pre_ref_fullname":"Name","pre_ref_position":"Job","pre_ref_phone":"Number"},{"pre_ref_fullname":"Name2","pre_ref_position":"Job2","pre_ref_phone":"Number2"}]

let result = data.filter(o => Object.values(o).some(e => e.trim() !== ""));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the filter method:

```
let filtredArr = arr.filter(ele => ele.pre_ref_fullname && ele.pre_ref_position && ele.pre_ref_phone)
```

Since empty strings return false you don't need to add comparisons if this is the only case to filter out elements in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter` with `Object.values` and `every`, and use `trim` to make sure it excludes whitespace:

```js
const data = [{pre_ref_fullname:"",pre_ref_position:"",pre_ref_phone:""},{pre_ref_fullname:"",pre_ref_position:"",pre_ref_phone:""},{pre_ref_fullname:"",pre_ref_position:"",pre_ref_phone:""},{pre_ref_fullname:"Name",pre_ref_position:"Job",pre_ref_phone:"Number"},{pre_ref_fullname:"Name2",pre_ref_position:"Job2",pre_ref_phone:"Number2"}];

const res = data.filter(e => Object.values(e).every(s => s.trim != ""));

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```