# Angular remove null values of JSON object

Tags: json, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I need to remove the null values of JSON object before requesting a post. My below code doesn't work, could you please let me know where I'm going wrong?

```
publish() {
    let resource = JSON.stringify(this.form.value)
        const removeEmpty = (obj) => {
      Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
         if (obj[key] && typeof obj[key] === "object") {
           removeEmpty(obj[key]);
         } else if (obj[key] === null) {
           delete obj[key];
         }
       });
       return obj;
    };
    console.log("new obj :" + removeEmpty(resource));
}
```

[Stackblitz for sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qyz4tm)

Comment: You can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23774231/how-do-i-remove-all-null-and-empty-string-values-from-an-object

Answer (score 0):

Your `resource` is a string, since you stringify your object. Please remove the stringify.

```
publish() {
    let resource = this.form.value;
        const removeEmpty = (obj) => {
      Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
         if (obj[key] && typeof obj[key] === "object") {
           removeEmpty(obj[key]);
         } else if (obj[key] === null) {
           delete obj[key];
         }
       });
       return obj;
    };
    console.log("new obj :", removeEmpty(resource));
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion.
But still it displays the null object in the console after removed.