# If value of a property is null when updating then that property should not be added to the record

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Suppose I have a mongoose schema like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var testSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    nickName: {type: String}
});

var Test = module.exports = mongoose.model('Test', testSchema);
```

I declare methods for CRUD operation using variable Test. From that one such method is update, which is defined as follows:

```
module.exports.updateTest = function(updatedValues, callback) {

    console.log(updatedValues); //this output is shown below

    Test.update(
        { "_id": updatedValues.id },
        { "$set" : { "name" : updatedValues.name, "nickName" : updatedValues.nickName } },
        { multi: false },
        callback
    );

};
```

Now, I use this method inside my node router as follows:

```
router.put('/:id', function(req, res, next) {

    var id = req.params.id,
    var name = req.body.name,
    var nickName = req.body.nickName

    req.checkBody("name", "Name is required").notEmpty();

    var errors = req.validationErrors();

    if(errors) { ........ }
    else {

        var testToUpdate = new Test({
            _id: id,
            name: name,
            nickName: nickName || undefined
        });

        Test.updateTest(testToUpdate, function(err, result) {
            if(err) { throw(err); }
            else { res.status(200).json({"success": "Test updated successfully"}); }
        });

    }
});
```

Now if I save a new record in database and then see it in database then it looks like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("ns8f9yyuo32hru0fu23oh"), //some automatically generated id 
    "name" : "firstTest",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Now if I update the same document without changing anything and then if I take a look at same record in database, then I get:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("ns8f9yyuo32hru0fu23oh"), //some automatically generated id 
    "name" : "firstTest",
    "__v" : 0,
    "nickName" : null
}
```

Can you see that nickName is set to null? I don't want it to work like this. I want that if my property is null, then that property should not be included in the record.

If you remember, I have console logged the updatedValues before updating it. (see the second code block in question). So, here is the logged values:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("ns8f9yyuo32hru0fu23oh"), //some automatically generated id 
    "name" : "firstTest"
}
```

I don't know why, but nickName is not present in the logged values and then after update I get `nickName: null`. I think, the problem lies in second Code block. Can you please check it?

**Note:**

Actually I have lot more fields in my schema than I specified in question. Some fields are reference to other records as well.

Comment: seems you want to use one of these techniques on the value of `$set`.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286141/remove-blank-attributes-from-an-object-in-javascript

Comment: Scanning through the answers and comments, it seems that this isn't your true question, if true, please update your question so we can help you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wouldn't write this this way, but I'll tell you why your code is failing.

The problem is your $set block

You're choosing to specifically set the value to the update object passed in. If the value is `undefined` you're forcing mongo to set that to `null`.

Here's the problem

example, in DB:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("ns8f9yyuo32hru0fu23oh"),
    "name" : "firstTest",
    "nickname": "jack",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

IF you pass in `testToUpdate = { name: 'foo' }` you'll end up with

```
 Test.update({ ... }, { $set: { name: 'foo', nickname: undefined }}
```

because you're getting `updatedValues.nickname` off of the arguments and thats not defined

What you **want** is

```
Test.update({ ... }, { $set: updatedValues }
```

which is translated to

```
Test.update({ ... }, { $set: { name: 'foo' } }
```

You're no longer providing a key for nickname, thus not making it set to undefined/null.

---

I would use a mongoose plugin and not worry about manually passing the fields all the way to your model (see [github.com/autolotto/mongoose-model-update](https://github.com/autolotto/mongoose-model-update))

- You can define the update-able fields and then you can just do `model.update(req.body)` and not worry about all this
- Even if you don't want to use the plugin you can still just do `Test.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { name, nickname }, callback)`

Comment: Thank you for the great answer.

Answer (score 8):

You can prevent such documents from updating in MongoDB by setting the runValidators option to true in the update method.

Ex:

```
  module.exports.updateTest = function(updatedValues, callback) {

    Test.update(
      { "_id": updatedValues.id },
      { "$set" : { 
        "name" : updatedValues.name, "nickName" : updatedValues.nickName } ,
      },
      { multi: false, runValidators: true },
      callback
    );
  };
```

In addition, you can also set the option omitUndefined to true to prevent undefined values from being reflected.

Ex:

```
  module.exports.updateTest = function(updatedValues, callback) {

    Test.update(
      { "_id": updatedValues.id },
      { "$set" : { 
        "name" : updatedValues.name, "nickName" : updatedValues.nickName } ,
      },
      { multi: false, runValidators: true, omitUndefined: true },
      callback
    );
  };
```

Comment: If you want to use `omitUndefined` in Mongoose 6, see [Mongoose docs: removed undefined](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_6.html#removed-omitundefined).  In Mongoose 6.x, the `omitUndefined` option has been removed, and Mongoose will always strip out undefined keys.

Answer (score 2):

Its true that the problem is your `$set` part as pointed in the other answers, but using if condition is not the best way to do this. What if there are multiple fields you might need multiple if conditions or even a separate function to deal with this.

Mongoose offers a really good option to deal with this:`{omitUndefined: 1}` , it will not update all the undefined values in your query.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a look at your code, there is a problem in your update method that won't help you to obtain the result you want.

This is you update code:

```
module.exports.updateTest = function(updatedValues, callback) {

    console.log(updatedValues); //this output is shown below

    Test.update(
        { "_id": updatedValues.id },
        { "$set" : { "name" : updatedValues.name, "nickName" : updatedValues.nickName } },
        { multi: false },
        callback
    );

};
```

The problem is in the `$set` part.

In mongodb you cannot unset a field in a document by just assigning `undefined` to it. You should use the `$unset` operator.

So your update code should be something like:

```
module.exports.updateTest = function(updatedValues, callback) {

    console.log(updatedValues); //this output is shown below
    const operators = {$set: {name: updatedValues.name}};
    if (updatedValues.nickName) {
        operators.$set.nickName = updatedValues.nickName;
    } else {
        operators.$unset = {nickName: 1};
    }
    Test.update(
        { "_id": updatedValues.id },
        operators,
        { multi: false },
        callback
    );

};
```

Note that the use of `$unset` is fundamental to remove the field if it already exists in your document.

Comment: Actually I have lot more fields in my schema than I specified in question. Some fields are reference to other records as well. Still I gave a try to your answer and I got an error when updating, which says: Cast Error: Cast to string failed for value " { ............ }", where in curly braces my object is shown.

Comment: I also have some hierarchical objects in my schema as follows: details: { mailing: { name: String, address: string }, contact: { mobile: string, email: email }}. The object above is shown as example. How can I update it?

Comment: Please ignore my first comment as it is solved which was my typing mistake.

Answer (score 1):

As you're using `$set` in the query which says in the documentation

> The $set operator replaces the value of a field with the specified value.

So you're forcing to set the undefined value which is `null` here to the field. Either you set `required : true` against the `nickName` field in the schema or try passing JS object instead of writing raw query like, 
Instead of :

```
Test.update(
        { "_id": updatedValues.id },
        { "$set" : { "name" : updatedValues.name, "nickName" : updatedValues.nickName } },
        { multi: false },
        callback
    );
```

Try doing:

```
var data = {  name : updatedValues.name };
if(updatedValues.nickName){
     data.nickName = updatedValues.nickName;
}
Model.update({ "_id": updatedValues.id }, data ,options, callback)
```

Check this link in [Mongoose documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update) for more information on the approach.

Comment: I have tried to use the answer provided by you. But it gives me an error saying that: CastError: Cast to string failed for value {............}, where in curly braces is my object.

Comment: OK, I was missing `.name` in data. Now, I also have some hierarchical objects in my schema as follows: `details: { mailing: { name: String, address: string }, contact: { mobile: string, email: email }}`. The object above is shown as example. How can I update it?

Comment: I'm assuming you want to know how to update nested values, Ideally it should work for nested objects as well. As, In mongo, to access a nested object you'd do it in the form of .(dot) operator.

Comment: I have tried it with dot operator, but I am getting an error : cannot set address of undefined. The error is very much descriptive. So, I tried to set `data.details = { }; data.details.mailing = { }; data.details.mailing.address = updatedValues.address;` Now I am getting another error: cannot set mailing and address together.

Comment: @Vishal You have to define inner object first. And I doubt if you can update multiple parameters as one parameter to $set

Comment: I can't understand your comment. can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are still adding the `nickname` property on the document - you're just setting it to `undefined`, but contrary to what you thought that's not the same as not setting it at all.

What you want is to not include the nickname property at all if it's undefined, which you can do like this:

```
module.exports.updateTest = function(updatedValues, callback) {

    const set = { "name": updatedValues.name };

    if (updatedValues.nickName) {
        set["nickName"] = updatedValues.nickName;
    }

    Test.update({ "_id": updatedValues.id }, { "$set": set}, { multi: false },
        callback
    );

};
```

Comment: Actually I have lot more fields in my schema than I specified in question. Some fields are reference to other records as well. Still I gave a try to your answer and I got an error when updating, which says: Cast Error: Cast to string failed for value " { ............ }", where in curly braces my object is shown.

Comment: I also have some hierarchical objects in my schema as follows: details: { mailing: { name: String, address: string }, contact: { mobile: string, email: email }}. The object above is shown as example. How can I update it?

Comment: Please ignore my first comment as it is solved which was my typing mistake.

Comment: @Vishal ok, so does that mean my answer helped?

Comment: I don't know if your answer works or not because I got error saying cannot set address of undefined.

Comment: My answer - and your question - doesn't include anything about an address at all so I don't know what's happened there, but it sounds like that's a separate question. First test my answer with a separate smaller schema for testing so you can check if that works. Then you can move on to the next question.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method I found is by using `lodash.pickby` you just pass `body` (or any object for that matter) and it removes all `undefined` and `null` fields and keys