# How to remove undefined property from object?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this object:

```
  this.prepaidObject = {
            'customerType' : this.prepaidDetailForm.prepaidDetails.customerType,
            'firstName' : this.prepaidDetailForm.prepaidDetails.firstName,
            'lastName' : this.prepaidDetailForm.prepaidDetails.lastName,
            'note' : this.prepaidDetailForm.prepaidDetails.note,
            'created': this.prepaidDetailForm.prepaidDetails.created
        };
```

Now sometimes some of this property are undefined. What i want is if one of `this.prepaidDetailForm.prepaidDetails` properties are undefined not to display them.  So for example if `this.prepaidDetailForm.prepaidDetails.firsName` is undefined i dont need to  create `'firstName'` property isnide object. Any suggestion how can i do that?

Comment: `if (typeof X !== "undefined")  this.prepaidObject["key"] = X;`

Comment: Why You want to delete added property if You can simply check and add only _"valid"_ properties?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check your object:

```
    for( var m in this.prepaidObject ) {
        if ( this.prepaidObject[m] == undefined ) {
            delete this.prepaidObject[m];
        }
    }
```

Comment: could we loop over objects ?

Comment: Yes, in the loop I post m becomes the member reference.

Comment: Honestly , that's brand new to me , X'D, I thought you could do it using the forEach of ES6 (e.g), but in this way , I do not know it.

Comment: this syntax has been around in Javascript for years, trust me it works.

Comment: PS: am not the one who asked, just coming through and saw it , here is a +1 :D

Answer (score 5):

The shortest way to do this is to `parse` it after `stringify`.

The exact syntax:

```
let prepaidObjectNew = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(prepaidObject))
```

**Example**

Before:

```
var prepaidObject = {
    'customerType' : 'TestCustType',
    'firstName' : "sample FirstName",
    'lastName' : "sample LastName",
    'note' : undefined
 };
```

After:

```
{
    'customerType' : 'TestCustType',
    'firstName' : "sample FirstName",
    'lastName' : "sample LastName"
 };
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to go through the keys and only append the defined ones:

```
this.prepaidObject = { };
Object.keys(this.prepaidDetailForm.prepaidDetails)
     .forEach(function(key) {
           var val = this.prepaidDetailForm.prepaidDetails[key];
           if (val !== undefined) {
                this.prepaidObject[key] = val;
           }
     });
```

This is assuming the keys in `prepaidObject` are the same as in `prepaidDetails` and all of them follow the same rule you mention.

Especially if you're using ES6 you might make this more elegant using `map` and `reduce` like so:

```
this.prepaidObject = Object.keys(this.prepaidDetailForm.prepaidDetails)
     .map(key => ({key, val: this.prepaidDetailForm.prepaidDetails[key]}))
     .reduce((obj, {key, val}) => {
          if (val !== undefined) {
               obj[key] = val;
          }
          return obj;
     }, {});
```

And an even more succinct approach using more ES6 features:

```
this.prepaidObject = Object.keys(this.prepaidDetailForm.prepaidDetails)
     .map(key => ({key, val: this.prepaidDetailForm.prepaidDetails[key]}))
     .filter(({_, val}) => val !== undefined)
     .reduce((obj, {key, val}) => Object.assign(obj, { [key]: val }), {});
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [Lodash](https://lodash.com/) make it too easy in one line:

```
_.pickBy(this.prepaidObject, _.identity);
```

That would remove all **falsey** values

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to check the type.

```
(typeof(this.prepaidDetailForm.prepaidDetails.firsName) != "undefined") ? this.prepaidDetailForm.prepaidDetails.firsName : ''
```

Its basically:

```
var firstName = '';
if(typeof(this.prepaidDetailForm.prepaidDetails.firsName) != "undefined")
     firstName = this.prepaidDetailForm.prepaidDetails.firsName;
```

Comment: that is a bit naughty , it should be kicked out automatically , not testing on a fixed key's value. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Please try following:

```
 for (var propName in this.prepaidObject) { 
    if (this.prepaidObject[propName] === undefined) {
      delete this.prepaidObject[propName];
    }
  }
```

And look at following answers: 
[Remove blank attributes from an Object in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286141/remove-blank-attributes-from-an-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

```
this.prepaidObject = {};
for (var i in this.prepaidDetailForm.prepaidDetails) {
  if (typeof(this.prepaidDetailForm.prepaidDetails[i]) !== 'undefined') {
    this.prepaidObject[i] = this.prepaidDetailForm.prepaidDetails[i];
  } 
}
```

If you want to exclude also null values and undefined, change the condition to:

```
if (this.prepaidDetailForm.prepaidDetails[i] != null)
```

Not the double ==. because `null == undefined` but `null !== undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have an object like below one,

```
var prepaidObject = {
    'customerType' : 'TestCustType',
    'firstName' : "sample FirstName",
    'lastName' : "sample LastName",
    'note' : undefined
 };
```

You can remove undefined using JSON.parse and JSON.stringify method,

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(prepaidObject));
console.log(prepaidObject)
```

Output will be,

```
{
    'customerType' : 'TestCustType',
    'firstName' : "sample FirstName",
    'lastName' : "sample LastName"
 }
```