# Axios conditional parameters

Tags: javascript, axios

```
axios.get(globalConfig.FAKE_API, {
    params: {
        phone: this.phone,
        mail: this.mail
    },
})
.then((resp) => {
    this.req = resp.data
 })
.catch((err) => {
     console.log(err)
 })
```

Is there any way I can make conditional parameters when doing GET / POST requests with Axios? For example, if my `mail` parameter is empty, i won't send an empty parameter, like: `someurl.com?phone=12312&mail=`

Comment: Take a look at it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/38340730/4248342

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove blank attributes from an Object in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286141/remove-blank-attributes-from-an-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Either you can maintain a variable of `params` before making a request and only add key if it has data like:

```
const params = {}
if (this.mail) { params.mail = this.mail }
```

or you can do like below, we write normal js code between `...()` the parenthesis. We are adding a ternary condition.

```
axios.get(globalConfig.FAKE_API, {
  params: {
    phone: this.phone,
    ...(this.mail ? { mail: this.mail } : {})
  },
})
```

Comment: What does `...` means? Also can i put condition inline? like `mail !==  undefined ? true : false`

Comment: this is the spread operator https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax. No, you cannot do this `mail !== undefined ? true : false`

Comment: Used `...({ mail: this.mail })`, but my get request is still appending this `http://fake.com/users?phone=123&mail=`

Comment: Are you sure the object spread operator does what you expect? I just tested it in the Firefox console and using the object spread operator did not omit empty/null values

Comment: oh, my bad, forgot to add the condition, updated the answer.!

Comment: @RaghavGarg, also why do you put `mail` as object?

Comment: spread operator take all the keys from source object and add those keys to target object, since we wanted the key `mail` on our param object that's why. Let me know if it doesn't make any sense.!

Answer (score 1):

Reghav Garg's idea looks neat at first glance, but with more than one optional parameter, I'm afraid it will get messy.

You could simply use one of the common utility libraries like underscore or lodash and utilize their `filter` function:

```
const allParams = {
    mail: this.mail,
    phone: this.phone,
    // ...
};
axios.get(globalConfig.FAKE_API, {
   // 'Pick' takes only those elements from the object
   // for which the callback function returns true
   //
   // Double negation will convert any value to its boolean value,
   // so null becomes false etc.
   params: _.pick(allParams, (value, key) => { return !!value; })
})
```

Comment: well, you are right. I would not suggest my answer for bulk property checks.

Comment: What's for is `(value, key)`?

Comment: It's the arrow function syntax, kind of like a shorthand for `function(value, key) { ... }`, but with sideeffects like no own `this` object. Its great to declare callbacks: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: What do i put as value, key in my case?

Comment: You don't have to put anything there. `(value, key) => { return !!value; }` defines a callback function. That callback function will be called by `_.filter` for each of the elements in `allParams`. For each call, `value` will be the current value (i. e. the content of `this.mail`) and `key` will be the current key (i. e. 'mail'). The function then uses the value to check whether the current element is empty and should be included in the returned object or not.

Comment: i'm getting `users?0=1&1=0` values, when using your solution.

Comment: My bad, `_.filter` can only be used with collections (= arrays) and always returns an array. `_.pick` is the correct function: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#pick