# Making request parameter optional in axios get request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-router, httprequest

I have below axios request.

```
import axios from 'axios';
axios.get('/user', {
    params: {
      ID
      Name
    }
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
```

I want all the `request parameter` should be `optional`. if user send `ID` then it should give `ID`, if user enter `ID and Name` it should consider `both`. If user enters `none` it should display `all the record`.

I dont know how to handle this in react.

Comment: you can see this post. I think you got your answer from this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52312919/axios-conditional-parameters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

think u are looking for something like below:

```
params: {
   ...(ID && {
      ID: ID
    }) // conditional spread operator
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You would evaluate the params in a variable based on a condition before giving them to axios:

```
const parameters = condition ? {ID: id, Name: name} : {};
axios.get('/user', {
params: parameters
})
.then(function (response) {
console.log(response);
})
```