# Ignore properties set undefined on GET request in Angular with Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to request some data from the server. When I change a property's model to undefined this "undefined" string is sent in the query string.

```
let filterModel = new GroupFilterModel();
filterModel.status = anycondition ? "opened" : undefined;
this.http.get<GroupModel[]>("apiurl", { params: filterModel });
```

The querystring sent is something like this:

```
apiurl?status=undefined
```

I want to avoid sending the status variable. How can I have this behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this one liner in ES6:

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => obj[key] === undefined ? delete obj[key] : '');
```

As if:

```
filterModel.status = anycondition ? "opened" : undefined;
const model = Object.keys(filterModel).forEach(key => obj[key] === undefined ? delete obj[key] : '');
this.http.get<GroupModel[]>("apiurl", { params: model });
```

You can go even further and make it an extension on the object:

```
Object.prototype.StripUndefined = function StripUndefined() {
  return this.keys(filterModel).forEach(key => obj[key] === undefined ? delete obj[key] : '');
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove properties that have undefined and null values with lodash as follows:

```
let filterModel = new GroupFilterModel();
filterModel.status = anycondition ? "opened" : undefined;
this.http.get<GroupModel[]>("apiurl", { params: _.pickBy(filterModel) });
```

For other solutions using vanilla JS see:

[Remove blank attributes from an Object in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286141/remove-blank-attributes-from-an-object-in-javascript)