# How to update if key exists - sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I want to update my database if the key of the request exists.

this is my update action:

```
      shopsModel.Shop.update({
        name: req.body.name,
        province: req.body.province,
        city: req.body.city,
        address: req.body.address,
        username: req.body.username,
        type: req.body.type,
        ...
```

For example, I want to update the `name` column if `req.body.name` is not empty. 
What is the shortest way to do this?

Comment: What is your database?

Comment: my database is `postgres`

Comment: Do you have something started already? like the connection to the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go :

```
let request = {
        name: req.body.name,
        province: req.body.province,
        city: req.body.city,
        address: req.body.address,
        username: req.body.username,
        type: req.body.type,
        ...
}

// With the help of Lodash
request = _.pickBy(request, _.identity); // <--- Will remove empty | null | undefined
```

Or you can use [Remove blank attributes from an Object in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286141/remove-blank-attributes-from-an-object-in-javascript) , and use that value for updating model

And then just simply :

```
shopsModel.Shop.update(request,...);
```

> **NOTE :**
>
> As I can see that key name and `req.body` names are almost same , so you
>   can directly use
>
> ```
> let request = req.body;
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Try below with use of `nullish coalescing`:

```js
    shopsModel.Shop.update({
       name: req.body.name ?? undefined,
       province: req.body.province ?? undefined,
       city: req.body.city ?? undefined,
       address: req.body.address ?? undefined,
       username: req.body.username ?? undefined,
       type: req.body.type ?? undefined
    })
```

It provides **returning only keys you want to update** and as a result **changing only those columns** in DB.

You can create a helper function for it:

```
const  returnIfNotNil = key => key ?? undefined
```

and use as above

```js
    shopsModel.Shop.update({
       name: returnIfNotNil(req.body.name),
       province: returnIfNotNil(req.body.province),
       city: returnIfNotNil(req.body.city),
       address: returnIfNotNil(req.body.address),
       username: returnIfNotNil(req.body.username),
       type: returnIfNotNil(req.body.type)
    })
```

or make even more consistent (assuming you use all body to update):

```js
// get only defined fields
const getOnlyDefinedFields = (body: Body) = Object.entries(body)
   .reduce((acc, [key, value]) => ({
      ...acc,
      [key]: returnIfNotNil(value) 
   }), {})
const data = getOnlyDefinedFields(req.body)

await shopsModel.Shop.update(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have your psql connection you can do simply like this:

```
if(req.body.name) {
    client.query('UPDATE table SET name=($1)', [name]);
}
```

replace table with your table name...
check this for more info: https://mherman.org/blog/postgresql-and-nodejs/ . (at update section)