# add variable to object if not undefined using short-hand

Tags: javascript, object

I'm trying to pretty much make my code clean and pretty.

I have something like this

```
let {name, city, address} = param.allParams()
let attr = {}

if (name) {

  attr.name = name
}
```

I wanted to see how I can condense even more. I tried this for example:

```
let {name, city, address} params.allParams()
let attr = {
  ... name,
  ... city, 
  ... address
}
```

I'm not sure I know what I was doing with the above example, but I'm experimenting and exploring javascript as well. Is there a better method to this?

thanks.

update: solution based on @Pointy comments

```
async update(req, res) {

    try {

      const results = await Company.update({id: req.params.id}, req.allParams())

      return res.ok(results)

    } catch (e) {

      return res.serverError(e)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Those two pieces of code do significantly different things. What is it that you're trying to achieve?

Comment: if a `param.name` is not undefined. to add it to the `attr` object

Comment: You don't have to extract the contents of `param` into separate variables if that's all you want to do.

Comment: oh shoot, your right!

Comment: That solution looks like it might not be safe. Are there fields other than `name`/`city`/`address` that a user shouldn’t be able to update? Maybe that has the potential to update `id`? What’s the ORM?

Comment: one possible way is instead of `... name,` use `... (name && {name}),`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove blank attributes from an Object in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286141/remove-blank-attributes-from-an-object-in-javascript)

Comment: im using sails.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless `param.allParams()` is not something you control, you should not add undefined properties to your returning object.

---

If the shortest is what you are looking for, JSON.stringify removes undefined properties.

```
attr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(param.allParams()))
```

Also, this is the cleanest method:

```
var params = param.allParams();

Object.keys(params).forEach((key) => (params[key] === null) && delete params[key]);
```