# Remove null/empty values from object

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have the following object

```
params: {
  filter: {
     status: '',
     color: 'red'
  }
}
```

And I need to remove empty/null values from the params object.
How can I do that ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove blank attributes from an Object in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286141/remove-blank-attributes-from-an-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Use Object.keys to iterate through the keys. Use the `delete` operator when encountering an empty/null value. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

Make sure to handle cases where an object is nested indeterminately deep.