# Angular 8: Remove empty Object from array

Tags: arrays, angular, angular8

Im using Angular8, want to remove empty object from an array, and get its length

```
Array: [
{data01: "abc", data02: "cde", data03: "fgh", data04: "", data05: ""},
{data01: "abc", data02: "cde", data03: "", data04: "", data05: ""},
{data01: "abc", data02: "cde", data03: "fgh", data04: "ijk", data05: "lmn"},
{data01: "abc", data02: "", data03: "", data04: "", data05: ""},
]
```

then I want it be like

```
Array: [
{data01: "abc", data02: "cde", data03: "fgh"},
{data01: "abc", data02: "cde"},
{data01: "abc", data02: "cde", data03: "fgh", data04: "ijk", data05: "lmn"},
{data01: "abc"},
]
```

is that anyway to do it ?

I tried to push those element in a new array like

```
_Array: ["abc","cde", "fgh", "", "", ....]
```

and chunk it by 5 then filter(Boolean), it works, but the performance was bit slow, any other way to improve the performance?

Comment: How about this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/286162/11719787

Comment: Can you include your existing code in the question?

Comment: `arr.map(i => Object.entries(i).filter(([k,v]) => v).reduce((acc,[k,v]) => ({...acc, [k]: v}), {}))`

Comment: ur code was nice, but I want to get the length, but ur code seems can't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the map() and filter() of Array object methods in JS to solve the problem.

```js
let array = [
{data01: "abc", data02: "cde", data03: "fgh", data04: "", data05: ""},
{data01: "abc", data02: "cde", data03: "", data04: "", data05: ""},
{data01: "abc", data02: "cde", data03: "fgh", data04: "ijk", data05: "lmn"},
{data01: "abc", data02: "", data03: "", data04: "", data05: ""},
]; // array provided

array = array.map(object => {
          let entries = Object.entries(object); //for each element in the array get the entries, [key, value] pair
          entries = entries.filter(([key, value]) => value !== ""); // remove the elements which has "" values
          return Object.fromEntries(entries);
          });
console.log(array.length);
// shorter version
array = array.map(object => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(object).filter(([key, value]) => value !== "")));
console.log(array.length);
```

There is a possibility the resultant array might contain an empty object if the input array had a object which had all the entries ""(empty string). Eg: {data01: "", data02: "", data03: "", data04: "", data05: ""}. In this case we need another filter() to remove the empty object from the resultant array.

```js
let array = [
    {data01: "abc", data02: "cde", data03: "fgh", data04: "", data05: ""},
    {data01: "abc", data02: "cde", data03: "", data04: "", data05: ""},
    {data01: "abc", data02: "cde", data03: "fgh", data04: "ijk", data05: "lmn"},
    {data01: "abc", data02: "", data03: "", data04: "", data05: ""},
    ]; // array provided

    array = array.map(object => {
              let entries = Object.entries(object);
              entries = entries.filter(([key, value]) => value !== "");
              return Object.fromEntries(entries);
              });
    // remove the empty object if present
    array = array.filter(object => Object.entries(object).length !== 0);
    console.log(array.length);
    // shorter version
    array = array.map(object => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(object).filter(([key, value]) => value !== ""))).filter(object => Object.entries(object).length !== 0);
    // the filter() at the  end removes the empty object
    console.log(array.length);
```

Comment: thats what Im looking for! but it will be better if can push the new array in 
```[key]: value```

Answer (score 1):

You may achieve this using pure JavaScript. Please try below code.

```js
var arr = [
{data01: "abc", data02: "cde", data03: "fgh", data04: "", data05: ""},
{data01: "abc", data02: "cde", data03: "", data04: "", data05: ""},
{data01: "abc", data02: "cde", data03: "fgh", data04: "ijk", data05: "lmn"},
{data01: "abc", data02: "", data03: "", data04: "", data05: ""},
]

arr.forEach(function(element){
for (var key in element) {
    if (element[key] === "") {
        delete element[key]
    }
}
});

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: its good, but Im try to get the length, but this code seems can't