# How to remove null, undefined value from javascript object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

this is my object . I am trying to remove empty array, empty string,null, undefined.

```
 let result = {
  a : [],
  b: undefined,
  c: null,
  d: NaN,
  e: {},
  f:{test: undefined, tes1: null,tes2:NaN},
  g:{name :{x:undefined, y:"s", z: null}},
  x:"sujon",
  y:"",
}
```

Now, I can only delete the undefined value from an object by using this code;

```
const removeEmpty = (obj) => {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    if (obj[key] && typeof obj[key] === 'object') removeEmpty(obj[key]);
    else if (obj[key] === undefined) delete obj[key];
  });
  return obj;
};

let res = removeEmpty(result) 

console.log(res)
```

my expected result would be like this:

```
   let result = {
      g:{name :{y:"s"}},
      x:"sujon",
    }
```

How can i get my expected result?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove blank attributes from an Object in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286141/remove-blank-attributes-from-an-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

After the recursive call, if the result is an empty object (with no own-properties), remove it:

```js
let result = {
  a : [],
  b: undefined,
  c: null,
  d: NaN,
  e: {},
  f:{test: undefined, tes1: null,tes2:NaN},
  g:{name :{x:undefined, y:"s", z: null}},
  x:"sujon",
  y:"",
  z:0,
}
const removeEmpty = (obj) => {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    if (obj[key] && typeof obj[key] === 'object') removeEmpty(obj[key]);
    if (
      (!obj[key] && obj[key] !== 0) ||
      (typeof obj[key] === 'object' && Object.keys(obj[key]).length === 0)
    ) {
      delete obj[key];
    }
  });
  return obj;
};

let res = removeEmpty(result) 

console.log(res)
```

Comment: OP is looking for a recursive approach, which requires notably different logic.

Comment: None of those do what OP is looking for.

Comment: That doesn't do what OP's looking for either. OP needs a check of own-property length after the recursive call in order to remove objects/arrays if they happen to be empty after processing.