# JS Remove empty keys from an object

Tags: javascript, object

```
const obj = {
  a: '123',
  b: '124',
  c: '1242414',
  d: '',
  e: '',
  f: ''
}
```

What's the right way to remove keys with empty values from an *object*?

Here's what I've tried, but can't finalize it..

```
Object.entries(obj).filter(item => item !== "");
```

Comment: do you want a new object or keeping the same object?

Comment: I don't mind both scenarios. Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove blank attributes from an Object in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286141/remove-blank-attributes-from-an-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4):

Using `filter` as you did, returns an `Array` instead of an `Object`. 
`reduce` is better, since it can return any type you wish.

---

### ES2015

```js
const obj = {
  a: '123',
  b: '124',
  c: '1242414',
  d: '',
  e: '',
  f: ''
}

// creates a new object, without empty keys
console.log(
  Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [k, v]) => v ? {...acc, [k]:v} : acc , {})
)

// or mutate the original object
console.log(
  Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, k) => (!obj[k] && delete acc[k],  acc), obj),
  obj // print original to prove it was mutated
)
```

Or another simple mutation:

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => !obj[k] && delete obj[k])
```

---

#### Classic javascript: (most efficient)

```js
const obj = {
  a: '123',
  b: '124',
  c: '1242414',
  d: '',
  e: '',
  f: ''
}

for(let k in obj)
  if( obj[k] == '' )
    delete obj[k]

console.log(obj)
```

You can write it as one-liner if you want it shorter :p

```
for(let k in obj) obj[k] == '' && delete obj[k]
```

If you know *keys* will never have `0` as values, you can do:

```
for(let k in obj) !obj[k] && delete obj[k]
```

Comment: using for..in throws eslint error - `for..in loops iterate over the entire prototype chain, which is virtually never what you want ...`

Comment: Your comment is very specific to your project's ESLINT configuration. I think it's an incorrect rule and whoever wrote this line *"which is virtually never what you want"* is mistaken, from my extensive, long, experience with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The `item` in your callback is an array containing the key and the value. So, return whether the second item in the array is something other than `''`, and turn it back into an object with `Object.fromEntries:

```js
const obj = {
  a: '123',
  b: '124',
  c: '1242414',
  d: '',
  e: '',
  f: ''
};
console.log(
  Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(obj)
      .filter(item => item[1] !== "")
  )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code step by step tells how to achieve this.

```
const obj = {
  a: '123',
  b: '124',
  c: '1242414',
  d: '',
  e: '',
  f: ''
}

const o = Object.entries(obj);
console.log(o);

const f = o.filter(keyValues=>{
 return  keyValues[1]!==""
});

console.log(f);

const filtered = Object.fromEntries(f);

console.log(filtered)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one using `forEach`. I do think using `delete` is most prudent when it comes to deleting object elements:

```js
const obj = {
  a: '123',
  b: '124',
  c: '1242414',
  d: '',
  e: '',
  f: ''
};

Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
  if(!obj[key])
    delete obj[key]
});

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing all **empty** and **null** from a object

```
const obj = {
  name: {
    first: "Max",
    middle: "",
    last: "Holder"
  },
  age: 45,
  address: null
}
function removeEmptyOrNull(obj){
    return Object.fromEntries(
     Object.entries(obj)
     .filter(([_, v])=> v!== null && v.length !== 0)
     .map(([k, v])=>[k, v === Object(v)?removeEmptyOrNull(v):v])
   )
}

  console.log(removeEmptyOrNull(obj))
```