# Remove empty [] from object in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

This is my service class method

```
public getSidebarItems(): Observable<INavData[]>   {

    //  let params = new HttpParams();
    //  params = params.set('userId', userid.toString());
      return this.httpClient.get<Result<INavData[]>> (`${baseUrl}/GetMenusByRoles`)
       .pipe(map( res => res.data));
      
  }
```

This is my json file recieved from api

*[{"id":1,"name":"Dashboard","url":"/dashboard","icon":"icon-speedometer","parentId":null,"parent":null,"children":[]},{"id":2,"name":"User","url":"/user/user-list","icon":"icon-list","parentId":null,"parent":null,"children":[]},{"id":3,"name":"Role","url":"/role/role-list","icon":"icon-folder-alt","parentId":null,"parent":null,"children":[]},{"id":4,"name":"Bank","url":"/bank/bank-list","icon":"icon-folder-alt","parentId":null,"parent":null,"children":[]},{"id":5,"name":"Branch","url":"/branch/branch-list","icon":"icon-folder-alt","parentId":null,"parent":null,"children":[]},{"id":6,"name":"Customer","url":"/customer/customer-list","icon":"icon-folder-alt","parentId":null,"parent":null,"children":[]},{"id":7,"name":"Transaction","url":"/transaction/transaction-list","icon":"icon-folder-alt","parentId":null,"parent":null,"children":[{"id":8,"name":"Test","url":"/report/transaction-report\n","icon":"icon-folder-alt","parentId":7,"children":[]}]}]*

***I have to remove  empty "children": []***

items$: Observable<INavData[]>;

```
 let result=this.sidebar.getSidebarItems();   
  this.items$ = result.pipe(
    map( sidebarItems => {
      return sidebarItems
      .filter( value=> Object.keys( value ).length !==0 )
     
   }));
```

The above code f[remove empty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38340730/7273263)

My Question is

1. Above code is not working .. i have to removeempty children with  node children":[].

Please let me know ..thanks

EDIT:

```
export interface INavData {
    name?: string;
    url?: string;
    icon?: string;
    childrens?: INavData[];
    ..other property
}
```

EDIT 1:

After updating code:

[image: Update]

```
 result.pipe(
        map(x => {
            return this.removeEmptyObjects(x);
        })
       ).subscribe(results => { console.log(results); });
```

Comment: You want to remove key from object which is empty, Correct?

Comment: yes @VimalPatel  ..i have to remove  "children":[]. (only empty childs)  Model is updated in the quesion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While looping through array of object. Grab the object information's using `object.entries`. This will give you keys and values as an array then after filter out empty array.
Loop through resultset and delete those keys from your main object.

```js
const { from } = rxjs;
const { map, reduce } = rxjs.operators;

var data =[{"id":1,"name":"Dashboard","url":"/dashboard","icon":"icon-speedometer","parentId":null,"parent":null,"children":[]},{"id":2,"name":"User","url":"/user/user-list","icon":"icon-list","parentId":null,"parent":null,"children":[]},{"id":3,"name":"Role","url":"/role/role-list","icon":"icon-folder-alt","parentId":null,"parent":null,"children":[]},{"id":4,"name":"Bank","url":"/bank/bank-list","icon":"icon-folder-alt","parentId":null,"parent":null,"children":[]},{"id":5,"name":"Branch","url":"/branch/branch-list","icon":"icon-folder-alt","parentId":null,"parent":null,"children":[]},{"id":6,"name":"Customer","url":"/customer/customer-list","icon":"icon-folder-alt","parentId":null,"parent":null,"children":[]},{"id":7,"name":"Transaction","url":"/transaction/transaction-list","icon":"icon-folder-alt","parentId":null,"parent":null,"children":[{"id":8,"name":"Test","url":"/report/transaction-report\n","icon":"icon-folder-alt","parentId":7,"children":[]}]}];

from(data).pipe(
  map(x => {
      return removeEmptyObjects(x);
  })
).subscribe(results => { console.log(results); });

function removeEmptyObjects(x){
      var emptyKeys = getEmptyObjects(x);
          removeKey(x,emptyKeys);
      if (x.children && x.children.length>0) {
        x.children.map(y=>removeEmptyObjects(y));
      }
          return x;
}
 
function getEmptyObjects(x){
return Object.entries(x)
    .filter(x => Array.isArray(x[1]) && x[1].length == 0);
}

function removeKey(obj,tobeRemoved) {
  if(tobeRemoved && tobeRemoved.length > 0) {
              tobeRemoved.map(key=> delete obj[key[0]])
   }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.3.3/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

**Edit 1**: updated the code for nested level removal.

**Edit 2** As it is returning array of object we need to use map function of that.

```
result.pipe(
        map((x) => {
          return x.map((y) => this.removeEmptyObjects(y));
        })
      )
    .subscribe((results) => {
      console.log(results);
    });
```

Comment: Thank you ..but ur code work only leve-0 objects..it remains in lev -1 i.e  "id": 8...Is it possible to all child elemants

Comment: Yes, that can be done, Do want to remove this logic for all the keys or just children?

Comment: I have updated the code for nested level also, please check.

Comment: But it is not removing when applied same thing in INav[] ..What could be the reason..?beacuse from api am assing to INavData[] and then i have to remove []

Comment: Does it not removing from all the objects or few?

Comment: not removing any one..updated code in qtn..Pls check  creenshot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227070/discussion-between-vimal-patel-and-ajt).

Answer (score 1):

use the rxjs `pipe` & `map` operator on the observable to transform the raw data to the format you desire.

```
this.sidebar.getSidebarItems().pipe(
  map( sidebarItems => {
     return sideBarItems
     .filter( value=> Object.keys( value ).length !==0 )
     .filter( value=> JSON.stringify( value !== '[]' ) )
     .map( (item: SideBarItem) => {
        return removeEmpty(item);
     });
  }
);
```

- the first map takes the value returned from the observable and allows you to operate on it

this allows you to subscribe to an shared Observable, but transform the values to the format you need.

Comment: Thanks .actullay my problem is i have to remove empty [] in object...i have updated the question