# can we get the object that we are dealing with by findOneAndUpdate?

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose

I am trying to make an put request to change some information. I get the new informations from request body, however I want some parameters optional

example:
**old record -->** {name: ugur, surname:k}

**put request comes like this**--> {name: uur}

so i want surname to stay same but it will be null now which i dont want to.

here is the code snippet :

```
await User.findOneAndUpdate({filter}, {$set:{name:req.body.name, surname:req.body.surname}})
```

In this way when user dont send a surname, users surname will be updated as null.
Is there a way to get users old surname? for instance -->

```
await User.findOneAndUpdate({filter}, {$set:{name:req.body.name, surname:req.body.surname || this.getsurname}})
```

I want to solve it without using if else or first findOne then update the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just don't include fields in update, if they are not provided (undefined or null):

```js
const update = {
  ...name && { name },
  ...surname && { surname },
}

await User.findOneAndUpdate({filter}, {$set: update})
```

`&&` operator returns right part of expression if first part of expression is truthy, `...` is a distructure operator, so basically `...name && { name }` means if name exists, add distructure `{ name }` into base object, to make things more clear, imagine we need to add property name equal to `request.body.name` to the object only if `request.body.name` exists: `{ ...request.body.name && { name: request.body.name } }`

Comment: I didn't understand what  ...name && { name } does? can you explain more please?
`const update = {...request.body.name && { name },...request.body.surname && { surname},}
`
gives me error

Comment: [Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38340730/13587169) i solved the problem filtering the ` object`, but if you can give me some topics i am willing to learn your way too.

Comment: `&&`  operator returns right part of expression if first part of expression is truthy, `...` is a distructure operator, so basically `...name && { name }` means if name exists, add distructure `{ name }` into base object, to make things more clear, imagine we need to add property `name` equal to `prop.name` to the object only if `prop.name` exists: `{ ...prop.name && { name: prop.name } }`