# Javascript removing null or undefined object from array of objects

Tags: javascript

The below format is fetching from server and its strangely adding `null` value in the last object. I want to remove `null` or `undefined` objecs from the array. Can anyone help me?

```
[
  {
    "addrSeq": "12",
    "addinfo": [
      {
        "virAddrSeq": "45"
      }
    ]
  },
  null
]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38340730/3297914
You should check your API return though instead of cleaning the object afterwards.

Comment: Duplicate of [Remove blank attributes from an Object in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286141/remove-blank-attributes-from-an-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let arr = [
  {
    "addrSeq": "12",
    "addinfo": [
      {
        "virAddrSeq": "45"
      }
    ]
  },
  null
];
arr = arr.filter((i)=>i !== null && typeof i !== 'undefined');
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter out `null` and `undefined` items by checking whether the item is not `null` (an `undefined` check is unnecessary, since `null == undefined`).

```js
const arr=[{addrSeq:"12",addinfo:[{virAddrSeq:"45"}]},null,undefined];

const result = arr.filter(e => e != null)

console.log(result)
```