# How To Delete an Empty State Input Value Before Sending in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

How to clear empty form input state in React before sending to server?

For example, in the form below, if `user.name` is not filled in then the object sent to the server is:

```
{ age: "19" }
```

**Note:** I can of course delete the empty properties manually in `submitHandler`, but is there any other way that doesn't require me to manually delete?

```js
const UserAdd = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({
    name: "",
    age: ""
  });

  const inputChangeHandler = (e) => {
    setUser({ ...user, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
  }

  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    // Start Solution
    const userWithoutEmptyProperties = {};
    for(const key in user) {
      if(user[key]) {
        userWithoutEmptyProperties[key] = user[key];
      }
    }
    // End Solution

    // send "userWithoutEmptyProperties" to server 
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={submitHandler} >
      <input type="text" name="name" onChange={inputChangeHandler} />
      <input type="text" name="age" onChange={inputChangeHandler} />
      <button type="submit">Add</button>
    </form>
  )
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have? It's simple, clear, doesn't create a lot of unnecessary intermediate objects, make a lot of unnecessary function calls, ...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I feel this is too wordy. I want to get the same behavior when I initialize state with an empty object, the problem with this React is giving me a warning.

Comment: Okay. The linked question's answers give you various alternatives, particularly [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38340730/157247).

Comment: Nothing different from the solution I wrote in `submitHandler`, I want to get another way, unfortunately my question is considered a duplicate, even though I already explained that I want to use another way, which should not be a duplicate.

Comment: What do you mean "nothing different from the solution I wrote"?? The first example in the answer I linked above is `let o = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).filter(([_, v]) => v != null));`. That's utterly and completely different from what you have in the question. (In your case, you'd change `v != null` to just `v` if you want it to match your test above.) Your question is considered a duplicate because it **is** a duplicate by SO's rules for duplicates, please see the [help] for details.

Comment: "I can of course delete the empty properties manually in submitHandler, but is there any other way that doesn't require me to manually delete?". Thank you i really appreciate your answer. I don't seem to be able to convey my meaning properly because of my language limitations.

Comment: So you want to avoid having "empty" values in `user` itself so you can send that directly, rather than creating a new object without them in `submitHandler`? (The confusion may be your use of "delete." Creating a new object without empty properties isn't *deleting* empty properties, it's just avoiding adding them.)

Comment: (Unrelated question: Shouldn't there be `value` properties on your `input` elements that use `user`'s property values?)

Comment: "Unrelated question": Yes I forgot not to write that in the example. There doesn't seem to be any other solution as I want, for the time being I'll be using the one I've created. Thanks for your answer, I got another way to remove empty property.

Comment: Okay, no worries. Just in case you did want to avoid having blank values in `user` in the first place, you could do it [like this](https://pastebin.com/NgiqWwqk). But I would probably just remove them (or create a new object without them) in `submitHandler` instead (as you do above). Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

```
Object.keys(user).forEach((item) => !user[item] && delete user[item);
```

Comment: That modifies the original object, which you must not do when objects stored in React state. Also, the OP said *"I can of course delete the empty properties manually in submitHandler..." which is exactly what this does. They're looking for a *different* solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one-liner:

`let o = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).filter(([_, v]) => v));`

More about this: [Remove blank attributes from an Object in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286141/remove-blank-attributes-from-an-object-in-javascript)

Comment: Please vote to close as duplicate when the answers to a different question answer a question, rather than posting an answer. More in the [help].