# Remove null attributes from an Object in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, null, undefined

As reference [Remove blank attributes from an Object in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38340730/6676781), how to make it Typescript compatible?

JS function (*nested objects | ES10*):

```js
function removeEmpty(obj) {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(obj)
      .filter(([_, v]) => v != null)
      .map(([k, v]) => [k, v === Object(v) ? removeEmpty(v) : v])
  );
}
```

I've tried with `Exclude<T, null>` but it doesn't works with nested objects and I think it's not the correct utility to use.

Note that the returned type should remove `null` type(s) but keeps `undefined`.

Example/Expected behaviour:

```
type TestType = {
  a?: {
    b?: {
      c: string;
    } | null;
    z?: {
      x: string;
    };
  } | null;
};

const testObj: TestType = {
  a: {
    b: null,
    z: { x: 'Hi' }
  }
};

const resultObj = removeEmpty(testObj);
```

Where `resultObj` type is similar to:

```
type ResultTestTypeExample = {
  a?: {
    b?: {
      c: string;
    };
    z?: {
      x: string;
    };
  };
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
type ExpandRecursively<T> = T extends object
  ? T extends infer O ? { [K in keyof O]: ExpandRecursively<O[K]> } : never
  : T;

type RemoveNull<T> = ExpandRecursively<{ [K in keyof T]: Exclude<RemoveNull<T[K]>, null> }>
```

Usage:

```
function removeEmpty<T>(obj: T): RemoveNull<T> {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(obj)
      .filter(([_, v]) => v != null)
      .map(([k, v]) => [k, v === Object(v) ? removeEmpty(v) : v])
  ) as RemoveNull<T>
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhDOwbmgXigbwLACgpQEMB+ALk133wCNTy9L8BjMxAJwEsA7AcwG4LKAXygAfKJwCuAGyn96+AF61s8ygA8WwDjzkNBuqMLGSZc-blyhIUAKJqwBTgBMAShEYTW8dgDcIUkAAeGAA+KHQYKAg1YAhneCgAeyoAK3dgASJYKJi4pwSuADMIVigAeSgsjCgAbQBpKC4oAGsIEETC8oBdMjsHZzcPL19-ILL6rrDhMk4IP1YBMhg5SxQoNwBbRL8AOWkpYLD0PsdXd09vPwDA6vrGzha2jtge2zVGKQknCEDN7Yg9jJghMQgAacT7KYhCw4KzQOCIcLrCBbXb7YIIJAoaE4XCFCScRjAdiJB6sFH-GwbMCgQ4ACmSKSWAEoyH80UDQnR8OTgJ4HmVUukAHSFViJDY2ThadgIOkCfCCtJE4VxGVyxnMhWUUXsKSxVh0uk1AD64J8XWZ4TCPigAEJ0CYpFrVPhhRsCGAjTVmubLdbar6oLbUKHykKiXSfFasuTURAqTSQFGrWQLS78FaCAl2QD0aFcIIgA)

Comment: I get this error:

Comment: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(o: { [s: string]: unknown; } | ArrayLike<unknown>): [string, unknown][]', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'T' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ [s: string]: unknown; } | ArrayLike<unknown>'.
      Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'ArrayLike<unknown>'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(o: {}): [string, any][]', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'T' is not assignable to parameter of type '{}'.ts(2769)

Answer (score 0):

```
export function removeNull<T>(obj: T | any) {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
    if (obj[key] && typeof obj[key] === 'object') removeNull(obj[key])
    else if (obj[key] == null) delete obj[key]
  })
  return obj
}
```

You can remove `null` elements with the code above. You can also give your type and it will remove all nested objects properties