# remove selected null properties from all objects of an array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter, ramda.js

I have an array of objects as below:

```
const arr = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'John',
    lastName: 'Smith’,
    note: null
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Jill',
    lastName: null,
    note: ‘note 2’
  },
{
    id: 3,
    name: null,
    lastName: ’Smith’,
     note: null
  }
];
```

I want to remove all null properties/keys from all the objects, except `note`. Note is a. non mandatory field in the ui. There are methods in ramda library which can help us remove null keys from objects. But is there a way to selectively preserve some keys even when they are null. Could anyone pls let me know.

the expected output is as below:

```
[{
    id: 1,
    name: 'John',
    lastName: 'Smith’,
    note: null
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Jill',
    note: ‘note 2’
  },
{
    id: 3,
    lastName: ’Smith’,
     note: null
  }
];
```

I have tried using the following code:

```
arr.forEach((obj) => {
    if (obj.lastName === null) {
    delete obj.lastName;
  }
  if (obj.firstName === null) {
    delete obj.firstName;
  }
});

return arr;
```

The above code works fine for limited amount of keys. But if there are lot of keys the code becomes cumbersome.

thanks

Comment: And what have you attempted? Please add that code to your question as a [mcve].

Comment: [Remove blank attributes from an Object in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286141)

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/3082296)

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/stackquestion-1-vxus33?file=/src/index.js

Comment: I don't know why this hasn't been reopened, as it seems a decent enough question after the edits.  You could do this: `const removeNullsExcept = (exceptions) => (o) => Object .fromEntries (Object .entries (o) .filter (([k, v]) => v !== null || exceptions .includes (k)))`, or if you really wanted a Ramda solution: `const removeNullsExcept = (exceptions) => pipe (toPairs, filter (pipe (evolve ([flip (includes) (exceptions), complement (isNil)]), apply (or))), fromPairs)`.  In either case, you could call it like this: `arr .map (removeNullsExcept (['note']))`