# Firebase Javascript V9 RTDB update: "values argument contains undefined in property"

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

A call like this can fail silently:

```
await update(ref, {...properties})
```

Even though this is a promise, using then/catch doesn't catch the error.
If you wrap the entire thing in try/catch, you can see the error:

```
try{
  await update(ref, {...properties})
} catch (error) {
console.log(error)
}
```

console:

```
Error: update failed: values argument contains undefined in property...
```

Since this was maddening, I wanted to share the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve it, wrap the properties in a function like this (adapted from [Remove blank attributes from an Object in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286141/remove-blank-attributes-from-an-object-in-javascript))

```
function removeUndefinedValues(obj: any): any {
  return Object.entries(obj)
    .filter(([_, v]) => v !== undefined)
    .reduce((acc, [k, v]) => ({ ...acc, [k]: v === Object(v) ? removeUndefinedValues(v) : v }), {});
}

await update(ref, removeUndefinedValues({...properties}))
```

Poof, no more silent failure